# $(this) and this, what difference?

Tags: jquery

Could someone please explain a bit, what difference between them?

For example I could do that with "that":

```
var bar;
button.click(function () {
    if (bar == this) {
        alert('same');
    }
    bar = this;
});
```

and couldn't with $(that):

```
var bar;
button.click(function(){
  if(bar == $(this)) {alert('same');}
  bar = $(this);
});
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your second example doesnt work, because every time you use the `$(this)` function, it returns an **unique** jQuery Object:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
var b = $(a);
var c = $(a);
```

Now, **b** and **c** are both unique jQuery instances.

```
console.log(c == b) // prints false
```

When using jQuery click events, `this` is the event.currentTarget in the callback, which is the HTML element that bound the click:

```
button.click(function(e) {
    console.log (e.currentTarget == this) // prints true
})
```

`$(this)` or `jQuery(this)` is a function that returns the HTML element wrapped in a unique jQuery Object, and contains all jQuery prototypes.

Answer (score 7):

`this` is the plain Javascript object.

`$(this)` is a jQuery wrapped element. You are allowed to call jQuery methods with it.

Comment: Wow! Fast responces.

Thanks, got it now. :)

Answer (score 1):

`$(this)` creates a jQuery object containing `this`.  `this` is the `HTMLElement` representing the button which was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Here's [quite a good page](http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/) that explains it in detail with examples.

(Note: It was also the first google result for "jquery this")