# Why do I have to use $(this)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery $(this) vs this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this)

In jquery sometimes I find that within a function I have to use `$(this)` because `this` won't work:

```
var listItems = $('li');
listItems.each(function(index) {
    $(this).css({ 

    })
})
```

Any ideas as to the reason why?

Comment: to turn a DOM object to a jQuery object

Answer (score 29, accepted):

- `$()` is the `jQuery constructor` function
- `this` is a reference to the `DOM element of invocation`

So basically, you're turning a `DOM reference` into a `jQuery object`

In your example, you could also use

```
listItems.each(function(index, element){
   $(element).css({
   });
});
```

..since `.each()` will pass both, index + element in its callback.

Answer (score 9):

I know I'm a bit late to this thread but I just wanted to bring up the fact that redundant wrapping of DOM objects is one of the most frequently committed crimes against jQuery. Taking care with your jQuery-instance constructing can have tremendous effects performance-wise and it's so easy to do that you have no excuse not to.

Typically, when people have a DOM object (whether it be referenced as `this` or `element`) they'll try to wrap it each time they need access to a jQuery method:

```
jQuery(this).css('a', 'b');
```

The problem is when you're doing this multiple times:

```
jQuery(this).css('a', 'b');
jQuery(this).find('span').attr(...);
jQuery(this)....
```

Every time `jQuery()` is called, a new jQuery instance is constructed. That kind of operation is expensive and should be avoided if at all possible -- especially in loops!

To avoid this, for one, you could utilise chaining with all methods that return a jQuery instance `$(this).css(a,b).attr(a,b)...`). The rest of the time you should have a locally declared variable that refers to the jQuery instance and then just use that:

```
var self = jQuery(this);
self.css(...);
self.attr(...);
```

If you're doing this within an `.each()` callback function, there is still a new jQuery object being constructed on every single iteration. You can avoid this by having one generic jQuery object which you continually mutate and then you can run jQuery methods off that single instance:

Look at this:

```
jQuery.single = function(a){
    return function(b){
        a[0] = b;
        return a
    }
}(jQuery([1]));
```

Now look at this:

```
$('a').each(function(i){
    $.single(this).append('Anchor number ' + i);
});
```

Only one jQuery object is being used. You can make it even faster by avoiding the identifier resolution:

```
$_ = $.single;
$('a').each(function(i){
    $_(this).append('Anchor number ' + i);
});
```

*Food for thought*. **More info here**: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/76-bytes-for-faster-jquery/

Comment: interesting approach. One comment said something about a possible memory leak there, was that approved / disproved ?

Comment: Hi J-P, Great post. I just don't understand the last bit. What's identifier resolution? Also on reading the article and the comments it does seem there are a few issues with this approach (memory leak, conflicting with the bind method), but all in all it's made me very aware of how jquery instances I invoke in my code.

Comment: @999, I came across this method in a book and think it is so amazing. But when I searched to check if everyone else was using it in real practice, I got only a few results including yours. Do you know why is it not popular? Or why it's not officially wrapped into jQuery?

Answer (score 8):

`this` is the native DOM element. `$(this)` is a jQuery object that allows you to call functions such as [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) on it.

Answer (score 4):

`this` is typically a DOM object by default, which means it only has the methods on normal DOM objects.

If you want to invoke a library-specific function (such as jQuery's `.css` function), you have to convert it to a full jQuery object first, which is what `$()` does by default if you pass it a DOM object.

(You can also pass other things to `$()`, such as an HTML string (to construct a new jQuery-wrapped DOM object) or a CSS selector (to get a set of jQuery objects that correspond to DOM objects matching the selector).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Firefox, try console.log($(this)) and console.log(this) to see the difference.

Comment: Actually, Firebug, not Firefox, or some other JS debugger.