# $(this) vs this in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

When writing JavaScript in jQuery is it best to do:

```
$('.select').click(function(e){
    $(this).something();
    //Or
    this.something();
});
```

Is there any difference? What are the advantages or disadvantages of either way?

Comment: `console.log( this, $( this ) );`

Comment: I have asked a similar question in the past, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363338/how-does-this-work-in-jquery

Comment: Keep in mind that `$` is a function. `$(this)` calls the function and passes `this` to it. Then you are doing something with the return value. If `$(this)` would simply return `this`, there would never be reason to actually call it. Hence `$(this) !== this` and `$(this).foo()` is potentially something very different than `this.foo()`.

Answer (score 3):

`$(this)` is a jQuery object and `this` is a pure DOM Element object. See this example:

```
$(".test").click(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
    //and
    alert(this.text()); // error no method
});
```

Answer (score 2):

They're completely different. Neither is "better" and you cannot compare their advantages and disadvantages. One is a jQuery object, one is a raw HTML element.

Comment: Maybe you should explain the difference, instead of declaring incomparability.

Comment: @salivan: *"One is a jQuery object, one is a raw HTML element."* that's the difference.

Comment: @FelixKling I don't think OP will get that.

Comment: That is not completely _right_. Using jQuery as library you should stay with jQuery if you do DOM manipulations. Except if you know what you are doing. If  jQuery is used on a single page web application and you do things like `this.parentNode.removeChild(this);` instead of `$(this).remove()` often, this could lead to noticeable memory leaks.

Comment: To clarify, I think that OP believes that if `$(this).something()` works then `this.something()` works. I'm under the impression he believes that choice of `$(this)` vs `this` is more or less a *stylistic* decision. I'm trying to tell him that it isn't.

Comment: @meagar you are right. upvote.

Comment: You should definitely clarify this before it could be considered a "complete" answer.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct, however I would like to add that `this` within the context of `$.fn.function` also refers to the jQuery object.

For example:

```
$.fn.function = function() {
  this.width();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the callback scope of jquery of an event handler `this` is the pure element.

`$(this)` would wrap it again into a jquery instance

So the result is very different and it simply depends on what you need...

Answer (score 0):

`this` and `$(this)` will give different results as `$(this)` is jQuery instance and `this` is HTML element.