# to get id of the dragged div while dragging if i hav many draggable div.using jquery

Tags: jquery

i have many dragged div. is there is any way to get the id of the dragged div while dragging.

```
$(".table_div").draggable({
    drag: function() {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        $(this).html(offset.left + ', ' + offset.top);

                     }
                         });
```

i am using jQuery Draggable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is always referenced to the `DOM element` of invocation.

So you can access `this.id` to get the current ID.

**update**

You have a read [Why do I have to use $(this)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316113/why-do-i-have-to-use-this/3316131#3316131)

`this` is a reference to your `DOM element` (a div)

`$(this)` is an `object`, created by the `jQuery constructor $ function`. You could also access the id by calling `$(this)[0].id`. But that would be unnecesary work obv.

Comment: thanks jAndy
i tryed with $(this).id 
it is resulted as undefined can you differ $(this).id and this.id
please because i am a beginner