# Difference between $(this) and this in jquery

Tags: jquery, this

What is the fundamental difference between using $(this) vs this

```
$('.viewComments').click(function(ev){
    //returns the desired value
    alert(this.getAttribute('id'));

    //Gives an error sayin function is not defined 
    alert($(this).getAttribute('id'));

    //returns the desired value
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

What I thought was "$(this)" will contain all functions that "this" has and more..But that doesn't seem to be the case.

So what exactly is $(this)? and

Hw do I know what functions are available when I'm using it? (I know I can get them through firebug. but I would like to know if there any some other way- some doc may be)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I have to use $(this)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316113/why-do-i-have-to-use-this)

Answer (score 156, accepted):

`this` is the DOM object, whereas `$(this)` is the jQuery wrapper around same.

When using `this`, you can call DOM methods on it, but not jQuery methods. When using `$(this)`, you can call jQuery methods on it, but not DOM methods.

Comment: So is it more advantageous or a best-practice to use $(this) over this in my jquery code?

Comment: @Sheldon: Of course. You want to be able to use all the juicy jQuery goodness, don't you? :-)

Comment: if so, how can I get DOM methods and jQuery methods only using one 'this' ?

Comment: @AldiUnanto Why would you want to do such a thing? You don't ever want to mix the two up.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young just for shorten way, if possible

Comment: @AldiUnanto Maintainable coding is not [golfing](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). :-) You really should not mix the two up if you want your code to stay maintainable. But if you really insist, there are some monkey-patching tricks you can use. You didn't hear this from me.

Answer (score 10):

**$(this)** - represent current DOM element on which event this function is called

**The this keyword** - In JavaScript this always refers to the “owner” of the function we're executing, or rather, to the object that a function is a method of.

Comment: It helps to note that `$(this)` represents the DOM element wrapped as a jQuery object *because* and *when* `this` refers to the DOM element as a native DOM API object

Answer (score 3):

In jQuery, this refers to the DOM object, and `$(this`) refers to the same object but with jQuery methods added

you can't call `this.each()` because each is not a DOM method, its a jquery method

you can call `$(this).each()` because `$(this)` returns a jquery object

Answer (score 2):

$(this) is the current object that was selected using a jQuery selector or event attached to the object.

so if you have `$('#myelement').click(.....` then `$(this)` referes to the element that was clicked on so that `$(this).hide()` hides that element.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two articles that you may find helpful:

[What is this?](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/08/what-is-this) by Mike Alsup

[jQuery's this: demystified](http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/) by Remy Sharp

Answer (score 1):

in jQuery the `$()` notation is a shorthand for the *jQuery selector*, so if you say `$(this)` you are asking jQuery to re-select your object. Then you have the usual jQuery functions available.
Then, `this` is the object selected by the outer jQuery call (JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

$(this) is a jQuery object and you can use the power and beauty of jQuery, but with 'this' keyword, one need to use native JavaScript.