# jQuery beginner ".each()"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why do I get an error in the console? "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;"

jQuery:

```
$("#menu a").each(function(){ 
console.log(($this.attr("href"));
});
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="selected"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="support.html">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="faqs.html">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you may use this.href

Comment: @LShetty note that `this.href` will give you the absolute URL in some cases, which may not be what the OP requires. `attr` gives you the exact string of the attribute.

Comment: You have an extra opening parentheses in your `console.log()`;

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you're right. I have updated my answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have mis-matched brackets, and `$this` should be `$(this)`:

```
$("#menu a").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `$(this)` and not `$this`.

And also you have an extra parentheses opened inside console.log

Something like this

```
$("#menu a").each(function(){ 
  console.log($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2qm237yb/)

```
$("#menu ul li a").each(function(){ 
console.log(($(this).attr("href")));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `this.href`

```
$("#menu a").each(function(){
    //to grab the absolutel URL
    console.log( this.href );
    //To get the string from href
    console.log ( $(this).attr("href") );
});
```

Comment: i'm still confused this vs $(this)

Comment: @causita, right, take a look at [the answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633270/difference-between-this-and-this-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

`$this` will return that kind of error since it's not defined while `$(this)` refers to each individual link (`<a href="#">`) and will work just fine.