# Write HTML in reference to attribute data with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to add a class to an adjacent element using the attribute of an anchor tag with javascript:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="swatchButton" data-color="blk"><span></span>Black</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="swatchButton" data-color="red"><span></span>Red</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="swatchButton" data-color="blu"><span></span>Blue</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="swatchButton" data-color="grn"><span></span>Green</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="swatchButton" data-color="yel"><span></span>Yellow</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var swatchColor = $(".swatchButton").data('color');
    $(".swatchButton").find('span').addClass(swatchColor);
});
```

I'm eventually looking for:

```
<li><a href="#" class="swatchButton" data-color="blk"><span class="blk"></span>Black</a></li>
```

Do I need to create some kind of array with `forEach()`?

Thanks!
http://jsfiddle.net/cL1rpk9L/

Answer (score 3):

use each() in jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".swatchButton").each(function() {
        var swatchColor = $(this).data('color');
        $(this).find('span').addClass(swatchColor);
    });

});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tamilcselvan/cL1rpk9L/3/

Comment: This works great, I just had to replace `addClass(swatchColor)` with `addClass(color) and worked a charm, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your code `var swatchColor = $(".swatchButton").data('color');` will return the `data-color` of the first element with class `swatchButton` and `$(".swatchButton").find('span').addClass(swatchColor);` will assign that value to each `span` element which is a descendant of an element with class `swatchButton`.

You need to set the color for each span individually

```
$('.swatchButton span').addClass(function(){
    return this.parentNode.dataset.color;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1w2crs0k/1/)

or

```
$('.swatchButton span').addClass(function(){
    return $(this).parent().data('color');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1w2crs0k/)

Comment: I see this is a more elegant solution, but takes me a minute to follow. How would you describe the difference between the 2 solutions? i.e. describe the difference between using `$(this).parent)()` vs `this.parentNode`

Comment: @user27068 one uses the jQuery method(`$(this).parent)()`) where as the other one uses vanila script(`this.parentNode`) only, so the vanila script based solution will work only on modern browsers(won't work in IE<=8)

Comment: Great, thanks for the reply! I also found this aka $(this) -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633270/difference-between-this-and-this-in-jquery