# $(this) throws "undefined" but this works as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please, consider two pieces of code.

1) Works as intended:

```
  $(function(){
    $('.menu  li').on('click', function(){
    var choice = document.getElementById("choice");
    var text = this.textContent;
      choice.textContent = text;
    });
     });
```

2) In this case, `$(this)` throws "undefined".

```
$(function(){
$('.menu  li').on('click', function(){
var choice = document.getElementById("choice");
var text = $(this).textContent;
  choice.textContent = text;
});
 });
```

I've been using `$(this)` as a reference to selected element for a long period of time. But today it failed. What's wrong? Should I forget about `$(this)` and never more be facing such a case in a few lines of simple code?

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/462960/pen/reJxWa?editors=1010)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633270/difference-between-this-and-this-in-jquery

Comment: You should use: `var text = $(this).text();` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.textContent` is [a DOM property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), not a jQuery property or method. This is why `$(this)`, which is a jQuery element, does not have it.

You can use `$(this)[0]` to get the actual DOM property out of the jQuery element, like that:

```
var text = $(this)[0].textContent;
```

However `$(this)[0]` is equivalent to `this` so there's no point doing so in that specific example. It might make sense in other cases - for example, if you get a jQuery element as a function argument:

```
function set_text(jqElem,txt) { jqElem[0].textContent = txt; }
```

You can also use [the jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/text/) `.text()` to get or set the text content of the element, like that:

```
var text = $(this).text();
```

Comment: May I assume that using this vs $(this), as a DOM method is the best way to avoid confusion if someone forgets the difference between DOM property and jQuery method?

Comment: @ВладимирМаксименко Mixing DOM and jQuery elements is acceptable, it is mainstream.
The reason is that jQuery elements are easier to use in many cases. However, when a simple DOM property is available for something, like the `.textContent`, it is much faster to use it than wrapping elements as jQuery elements. In this example one should use `this.textContent` because wrapping the `this` with `$(this)` cause an unnecessary processing.

Answer (score 0):

$() is the jQuery constructor function.

but this is a reference to the DOM element of invocation.

$(this), you are just passing the this in $() as a parameter so that you could call jQuery methods and functions.