# In JQuery, can I refer to a control using a variable name? I am trying to change the text of a label, but can't seem to find a way to refer to it

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the text of a label in JQuery, when that label is clicked.

This code works when I refer to the control ('ACCP') using its exact name:

`$("label[for='ACCP']").text("the new text");`

But I want to be able to refer to the control using a variable, not its exact name. This doesn't work:

`$("label[for=' + this.id + ']").text("the new text");`

I am quite sure the right control is behind `this.id`, because when I pop up a message to retrieve the id for the current control, it gives me the expected control name:

```
var ctrlName = this.id;
alert(ctrlName);
```

-> correctly returns 'ACCP' in this case.

I am probably missing an obvious syntax error in my code, but I never do JQuery - my code is all copy-paste ;)

Thanks in advance for your precious help,
JM

Comment: If `$("label[for='ACCP']").text("the new text");` works, and `this.id` is `ACCP`, then your code should work, can you make a [MCVE] so we can see the error for ourselves?

Comment: maybe you need to close double quotes before adding the `...'"+ this.id +"' ...`? Because looks like a string

Comment: Thanks guys, for the quick replies! Cheshire, you nailed it. It was the double quotes indeed. This works:         $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").text("the new text"); Thank you so much. I had been on this for 2 hours!

Comment: You are welcome, sometimes the smallest things you don't think they would break the code, they do. Also, I don't know which Code editor you are using, but in most cases, the color of the code changes to indicate you that you are using strings, functions, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the double quotes: https://jsfiddle.net/gz61mdbf/

```
this.id = 'new_code'
$("label[for='" + this.id + "']").text("the new text");
```

You are doing a string into the `for` without closing them, that's why is not working for you.

Comment: Thanks guys, for the quick replies! Cheshire, you nailed it. It was the double quotes indeed. This works: $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").text("the new text"); Thank you so much. I had been on this for 2 hours! ... And now I just feel stupid ;))))

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `$("label[for=" + $(this).id + "]").text("the new text");`?

Like told in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633270/difference-between-this-and-this-in-jquery):

> When using this, you can call DOM methods on it, but not jQuery
>   methods. When using $(this), you can call jQuery methods on it, but
>   not DOM methods.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Hi xKobalt, thanks for your reply. I tried that, but that didn't seem to work for me. Thanks again