# Help understanding jQuery's jQuery.fn.init Why is init in fn

Tags: javascript, jquery, initialization, prototype

I was looking over the jQuery to better understand how it works. The constructor basically just calls

```
new jQuery.fn.init
```

I was wondering what is the point of having the init inside jQuery's prototype? Wouldn't defining `init()` as part of the jQuery object itself serve the same purpose?

---

Basically I would like to know why jQuery's init function is located at `jQuery.fn.init()` and not `jQuery.init()`

Are there people doing this:

```
jQuery('a').eq(0).hide().init('div').slideToggle(); //?
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**EDIT:** Upon re-reading I don't think this answers your question, but it might be useful for someone's better understanding of how jQuery works anyway so I'm leaving it.

---

What is going on is that `jQuery()` is being defined as `jQuery.fn.init()` which is another way to say `jQuery.prototype.init()` which is the selector function!  What this means is that no one would call `jQuery.fn.init()` or `jQuery.init()` because `jQuery()` IS `.init()`!

What?

Let's look at the piece of code you're talking about:

```
// Define a local copy of jQuery
var jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
        // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
        return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
    },
```

In the comments it says just what I said, but more briefly.  But this is just the local copy of jQuery...  however, if you go to line 908 (of version 1.4.4) at the end of the self-executing function you'll see:

```
// Expose jQuery to the global object
return (window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery);

})();
```

...which means that this local `jQuery` becomes the global `jQuery`.  So?  So...  this local `jQuery` was actually `jQuery.fn.init()` right?  So what is `init()`?  If you look from lines 100 to 208 you'll see that it's the selector method.  What's the selector method?  It's that method you use all the time to find tags, ids, classes...  `$('#id')`, `jQuery('.class')`, `$('ul li a')`...  the selector function!

So no one would ever call `jQuery.init('div')` because it's a verbose version of `jQuery('div')` after that assignment.  And remember the `jQuery.fn` is exactly the same as saying `jQuery.prototype` so really all that part is doing is assigning `.init()` as a method of the prototype of the `jQuery` object.  I.E. a jQuery plugin.

Phew, that was a mouthful.  I hope this makes sense, and if anyone has any corrections in case I misinformed in any part of this lengthy explanation please let me know.

Comment: +1 for just sheer effort. So is there any particular reason to use the prototype as **opposed** to just on the jQuery object itself. Is it faster or something like that (I can't imagine that it is)

Comment: I don't have a good answer to that question, sorry.  I can hack at an answer, but certainty on this one is above my pay grade.

Comment: @MosheK. You don't need to use the prototyped version because when you make the call itself, it looks in the constructor (lets say for a method), and when it can't find it it looks deeper into the prototypes.

Comment: Keep in mind. Without `jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn;` `this` in `init` instance of `init()` function, not instance of `jQuery` object.

Answer (score 10):

`$()` is an instanceof `(new $())` is an instanceof `(new $.fn.init())`

The technique employed by jQuery is how you can achieve this. `$()` always returns as if it was called with the `new` keyword. However, instead of using a conditional switch on the `this` reference inside `function jQuery() {...}` it uses an external delegate object in all cases. This external delegate object, `jQuery.fn.init() {...}`, is given the jQuery prototype so that its object 'type' is of `jQuery`, and that all instances of it are actually instances of `jQuery`.

Comment: In light of the answer provided by @mVchr, this answer impressive. It provides a verbal definition of what would otherwise be an abstruse piece of code that would appear to provide only ambiguity. Thanks very much! But I still wish you had gone a mile or two further. This is definitely worth at least a chapter in a book.

Comment: While this is a great answer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1051797) adds more context.  If trying to resolve an error such as "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined": adding `[0]` after the jquery might help, i.e. `$('#myId)` would become `$('#myId)[0]`.