# Why sometimes jQuery selector returns something like "a.fn.init"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I don't know what happen to my Chrome browser, but all of sudden the behavior of doing `$('div#my')` in console is totally different from before. One time I've experienced this but later it somehow recovered, so I don't know how to reproduce it, and today it happened again.

Please watch the video:http://peaceevertvimg.org/jq.php.

In the video I do `$('div#my')` in two different browsers:

the first browser is not chrome but I believe it uses the chrome's kernel so its behavior is what I expect, and because currently my chrome is not working as expected so I have to use it to demonstrate my expection: when you do `$('div#my`)` you see directly the html TAG, and you can easily see the tag's html content, which is "something" in this case.

In contrast, in my chrome browser, the result is different, when I do `$('div#my')` I see an Object(`n.fn.init`), and I can't see the "something" immediately, which of course is very inconvenient. But before, I am pretty sure it was not like this, the behavior WAS exactly like that in the first browser.

The simple webpage in this video is http://peaceevertvimg.org/jquery.php, you can go test for yourself in chrome browser. And I am pretty sure most of you won't see the result as shown in my video. What happened to my chrome?(I've disabled all expansions and updated it to the latest version)

Comment: If you see `a.fn.init` that means that nothing was found to match the selector.

Comment: No. Its not. Look at this picture: http://peaceevertvimg.org/temp/s.png

Comment: You might want to check out this similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754560/help-understanding-jquerys-jquery-fn-init-why-is-init-in-fn).

Comment: I don't get that result when I try to reproduce it on this page. Try running `$('#somefakeid')` and `$('script')` on this page.

Comment: @shenkwen Not certain what Question is? What are you trying to determine? Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: OK! I've made a video, updating the question.

Comment: You're confusing [Chrome's developer tools' `$`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference) with jQuery's. They're not the same.

Comment: A video is not an explanation. We like text and code to read, not to watch someone else type it.

Comment: I remade the video and rewrote the question, hopefully it is less confusing now.

Answer (score 1):

If you open Chrome's developer tools console for any given page and simply invoke `$` you should see

```
$(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }
```

If you do the same thing on a page that has jQuery loaded, you'll see

```
function (a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)}
```

Evaluating `$($0)` is going to depend on the context of the page given the above information. You'll either get an element reference or a jQuery object.

Comment: I remade the video and rewrote the question, hopefully it is less confusing now.