# Why $('div#my') is returning Object Reference instead of HTML Tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I don't know what happen to my Chrome browser, but all of sudden the behavior of doing `$('div#my')` in console is totally different from before. One time I've experienced this but later it somehow recovered, so I don't know how to reproduce it, and today it happened again.

Please watch the video:http://peaceevertvimg.org/jq.php.

In the video I do `$('div#my')` in two different browsers:

the first browser is not chrome but I believe it imitates Chrome so its behavior is what I expect and what I have almost always been experienced. Because currently my chrome is not working as expected so I have to use it to demonstrate my expection: when you do `$('div#my`)` you see directly the html TAG, and you can easily see the tag's html content, which is "something" in this case.

In contrast, in my chrome browser, the result is different, when I do `$('div#my')` I see an Object(`n.fn.init`), and I can't see the "something" immediately, which of course is very inconvenient. But before, I am pretty sure it was not like this, the behavior WAS exactly like that in the first browser.

The simple webpage in this video is http://peaceevertvimg.org/jquery.php, you can go test for yourself in chrome browser. And I am pretty sure most of you will see the first behavior. What happened to my chrome?(I've disabled all expansions and updated it to the latest version)

By the way, is "HTML Tag" and "Object Reference" the right words to describe these two different outcome?

*************Update*************

If the video is not sufficient to understand what I ask and what I want to fix, these two pictures may help.

Picture#1: This is the "normal" behavior I've expected:
[image]

Picture#2: This is the current behavior I am experiencing:
[image]

You can see the big differences, the first one is much more intuitive, revealing key information immediately, while the 2nd one is not, at least to me. What causes this problem and how do I go back to the first one?

Comment: Thats post by me and I see it is closed because I rewrote it completely.

Comment: No it wasn't totally re-written, it's the same question - you shouldn't double post. (To give you an answer, I think I recall seeing `fn.init` instead of the element reference if I log a jQuery object to the console BEFORE I open developer tools - i.e. on page load, before I have had a chance to pop open my console - there's no difference in the object that is actually logged other than the way the chrome displays it in it's dev tools).

Comment: What you see in the other question is after I rewrote everything, but I see that question is put on hold(or closed?), probably because of poor composing before the rewritten. That is why I intend to close that one and post a new one here.

Comment: Except for the last sentence, this is almost word-for-word identical with your previous question.

Comment: If you revised the question because the original was closed, you should ask for it to be reopened, not post another identical question.

Answer (score 0):

`$('div#my')` doesn't return a DOM reference. It returns a jQuery wrapper around the found elements.

`$('div#my')[0]` would return a DOM reference. Or, forget jQuery and use:

```
 document.getElementById("my");
```

...and you will get a DOM reference directly

Also, since there should/will only ever be one element with a given ID, it is unnecessary to use `div#my`, just use `#my`.

Assuming we have a `<div id=someDiv>`, and then we write:

```
 console.log($("#someDiv"));
 console.log($("#someDiv")[0]);
```

Chrome shows this:

[image]

In the first log, we see that the result is a jQuery object that contains one element (the div). In the second, we see the element directly.

Now, depending on what version of Chrome you have, you may see the first one reported simply as [Object object], but that doesn't change the underlying result.

Comment: Would you please tell me what the behavior in your chrome? The 1st one or 2nd one?

Comment: @shenkwen it doesn't matter. The browser console display is not something that is standard across browsers, what matters is that it is returning an object, not a dom node or an array. How the console presents it to you is mostly irrelevant (other than often being confusing to the uninitiated.) If you want the dom node, use the jQuery method for that purpose: `.get(n)`

Comment: I understand the two outcomes are basically the same thing. But the problem is, with current behavior it is quite hard for me to work with it. First of all, you don't directly see the html content wrapper in the selected tag, secondly, when you mouse over it, the element don't get highlighted in the DOM.

Comment: Right. so log the dom node instead of the jquery object.

Comment: @shenkwen The two outcomes are NOT the same thing at all. One is an array-like object that contains the `div` and one is the `div` itself.

Comment: @KevinB But I am pretty sure previously I don't have to "log the dom node" to see the DOM reference, `$('#my')` would definitely show what I need to see. Isn't this an everyday experience of everyone using jQuery?

Comment: No. If you logged `$("#my")` and only saw `<div>...</div>` then you aren't using jquery. You may though have seen `[<div>...</div>]`. at some point. but even so, that and what you're seeing now are identical. Nothing you can do programatically will make it prefer one over the other, so if you want the dom node, log the dom node.

Comment: I am now only with my Mac so I can't prove what I say. But when I return to home I am going to make another video using my WIndow machine. I am pretty sure everything is just normal on that computer.

Comment: @shenkwen What the console shows you will vary from browser to browser, but the fact remains that jQuery works a certain way. jQuery selector results are packaged up into an "array-like" container and the DOM elements are IN that container. This is not machine-specific and not really up for debate. It's how jQuery works.

Comment: I think I make it clear in my question that on same computer and same browser, after a certain time today, the behavior became totally different. I don't know what this "something" is, but I need to go back to what it was like because this "new" behavior is affecting my efficency.

Comment: @shenkwen If you have a standard Chrome installation, then it is set to automatically update when a new version is available. This is entirely possible, but in the end, why is this a problem since the underlying code is not affected by how the console displays the value.

Comment: I've uploaded two pictures to show why it is affecting me.

Comment: @shenkwen And again, I ask you what the issue is? The first image indicates that you are getting an array and the second shows the more correct object, but both show you that you are getting an array-like object. Neither show a DOM element.

Comment: In my case, when you look at the first picture, you immediately see a google analytics script is loaded, while in the second one, I don't know how long does it take you to find whether GA is loaded, but to me it is another several minutes.

Comment: @shenkwen Pardon me, but if it is taking you several minutes to click the arrow next to the first array item, I can't help you. Also, like it or not, the second image is the one that I would expect in all browsers. I think you've just gotten used to a non-standard way for a browser to show you this.

Comment: It is not just a click, there are 15 script tags here, and to ensure finding out whether a target script is loaded, you have to click through all 15 tags and navigate through a lot of attributes of each one. Isn't that the case or did I miss anything? Or ofc I can write test script that is more powerful than `jQuery('script')`, thats the several minutes I am talking about.

Comment: @shenkwen This really isn't a big deal at all. Why can you just write `console.log(document.querySelectorAll("script[src*=google-analitics]"))`?

Answer (score -1):

From: Devx (http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/40923)

> Selectors let you select DOM elements so that you can apply
>   functionality to them with jQuery's operational methods. jQuery uses a
>   CSS 3.0 syntax (plus some extensions) to select single or multiple
>   elements in a document. You're probably already familiar with the CSS
>   syntax from HTML styling. Even if you're not, it's fairly easy to pick
>   up the key CSS selector features. I'll go as far as saying that jQuery
>   is the reason I really started to grok CSS. Using CSS syntax you can
>   select elements by ID, CSS class, attribute filters, or by their
>   relationship to other elements. You can even chain filter conditions
>   together. Look at this simple example, which selects all second-column
>   TD elements in a table using a simple selector: $("#gdEntries
>   td:nth-child(2)").
>
> The jQuery Object: The Wrapped Set: Selectors return a jQuery object
>   known as the "wrapped set," which is an array-like structure that
>   contains all the selected DOM elements. You can iterate over the
>   wrapped set like an array or access individual elements via the
>   indexer ($(sel)[0] for example). More importantly, you can also apply
>   jQuery functions against all the selected elements. - See more at:
>   http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/40923#sthash.l8Mo8CbH.dpuf

What you are seeing is said jQuery object returned by jQuery.fn.init().

What is going on is that jQuery() is being defined as jQuery.fn.init() which is another way to say jQuery.prototype.init() which is the selector function! What this means is that no one would call jQuery.fn.init() or jQuery.init() because jQuery() IS .init().

Some more info and a look at the jQuery code here: [Help understanding jQuery's jQuery.fn.init Why is init in fn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754560/help-understanding-jquerys-jquery-fn-init-why-is-init-in-fn)

As for a solution to your problem: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jquery-console-fix/jlmkkpkcgomkdpfhgjlpaaonhafnjgob?hl=en

Comment: Would you please tell me what is the behavior in your Chrome? And how do I go back to the DOM reference one? It is much more convenience to me.

Comment: @shenkwen I've updated my answer.

Comment: I briefly read the link, it is a little beyond my knowledge but I still don't understand why all of a sudden my chrome's behavior changed like this, and more importantly, how I can go back to the original behavior. Please be noted I've added two pictures to further clarify what I am asking.