# Jquery: strange behaviour

Tags: jquery, callback, this, element, jquery-events

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    mais_telefones();
    upload_imagens();
});

function mais_telefones()
{
    mais_telefones.click(function(event)
    {
        var label = input = button = null,
            labels = $('.telefones'),
            tamanho = labels.length;

        event.preventDefault();

        if (tamanho < 3)
        {
            label = $('<label for="elemento' + tamanho +
                '" class="telefones elemento' +
                tamanho + '">Telefone</label>');

            input = $('<input id="elemento' + tamanho +
                '" class="elemento' +
                tamanho + '"type="text" name="telefones[]" />');

            button = $('<button class="elemento' + tamanho + '">X</button>');

            button.click(function(event)
            {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('.elemento' + tamanho).remove();
            });

            label.insertBefore($(this));
            input.insertBefore($(this));
            button.insertBefore($(this));
        }
    });
}

function upload_imagens()
{
    var imagem = $('#imagem');
    imagem.change(function(event)
    {
        alert($(this).files);
    });
}
```

In `mais_telefones` function, I can use `$(this)`, append elements (`appendChild`), `insertBefore`, etc. But in the second function I can't. `$(this).files` returns undefined but `this.files` returns the values... What's wrong?

Comment: what is in the mais_telefones function?

Comment: What is `$(this).files`?

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass what `$(this)` is into the individual functions

for example:

`mais_telefones($('div'));`

and in the mais_telefones function:

```
function mais_telefones(sel){
     this = sel.get(0);
     ...
}
```

Comment: but why it works in the first function and not in the second one? Thank you.

Comment: what is `$(this).files` supposed to do? i have never heard of that function

Comment: it's not a jquery function. he's trying to access the native dom element which does contain a "files" collection for inputs of type="file"

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery: What's the difference between '$(this)' and 'this'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this) this could probably help you. excuse the pun :P

Comment: but imagem is a file input. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

jquery always returns an array of jquery objects.  You probably want this:

```
$(this)[0].files;
```

Comment: do you know why? When i say "this", i want the current object. In my first function I'm using this in insertBefore, take a look please. Thank you.

Comment: It's because $(this) returns a jquery object which does not contain a "files" collection.  You want the native javascript element and to do that you have to treat $(this) as an array.  .insertBefore() works because it's a jquery function