# This difference

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery $(this) vs this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this)

This code in this [video Tutorial](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/jquery-look-tim-van-damme/)

in a Very useful blog [jquery for designers](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/)

```
$('.navigation').each(function () {
    var $links = $('a',this);
    $links.click(function  () {
        var $link = $(this),
            link = this;
            if ($link.is('.selected')) {
                return;
        }
        $links.removeClass('selected');
        $link.addClass('selected')
    });
});
```

What is the difference between `$(this)` and `this`?

Please explain the simple difference in coding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Within the handler being pased into `click`, `this` will refer to the DOM element that the click handler was attached to. Calling [`$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) on it (`$(this)`) wraps that up in a jQuery instance, making various jQuery functions available to you.

In your quoted code, the `link = this` line is unnecessary as nothing ever uses `link`. The `$link = $(this)` line, though, creates a jQuery wrapper around the link so you can use functions like [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is) and [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass).

---

**Off-topic**

1. You probably want to change `if ($link.is('.selected'))` to `if ($link.hasClass('selected'))` so that jQuery doesn't have to parse the CSS selector.
2. You have a typo, the "o" in `removeClass` is missing.

Comment: +1 for the two code hints. Those are easy misses.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is native JavaScript that references the current `object` in `scope`.  `$(this)` is jQuery wrapped (adding additional properties) to that priormentioned object.  Examples:

**Plain JS**

```
var person = {
    SayGoodbye: function(){
        this.wave();
        this.exit();
    },
    wave: function(){
        //code to wave
    },
    exit: function(){
        //code to exit
    }
}

person.SayGoodbye();
```

**Some jQuery**

```
//a submit button
$('#myBtn').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    $(this).text("Submitting...");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// get everything with the class navigation
$('.navigation').each(function () {
    // get all anchor tags in that context
    var $links = $('a',this);
    // assign a listener for the click event.
    $links.click(function  () {
        // set $link = jQuery wrapper around this
        var $link = $(this),
        // set link = this;
        link = this;
        // if the link has the selected class do nothing
        if ($link.is('.selected')) {
                return;
        }
        //otherwise remove it and then add it again???
        $links.remveClass('selected');
        $link.addClass('selected')
    }); // exit anchor loop
}); // exit nav. loop
```

P.S. the link variable is unused above.

Comment: Thank you very much,,Yes, because this is only part of the code

Answer (score 0):

'this' is the DOM element as accessible by normal JavaScript, whereas when you turn this into $(this), you are creating a JQuery object with more jQuery added API out of that DOM element.