# Jquery on change reset to 0 and show alert

Tags: jquery

I try to get this code to work with the 3 input fields, but it works only with the first  :

```
<form>  
<p><input id="qty" type="text" maxlength="1"  /></p>
<p><input id="qty" name="text" type="text"  /></p>
<p><input id="qty" name="text2" type="text" /></p>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#qty").change(function(e) {
    if(this.value != '3' && this.value != '6' && this.value != '9') {
        this.value = 0;         
        alert('You can buy only 3, 6, or 9 pieces fromn this product');
    } });

</script>
```

What can be my error ?

Comment: You cannot have 3 things with the same ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have 3 things with the same ID try using classes instead:

```
<form>  
<p><input class="qty" type="text" maxlength="1"  /></p>
<p><input class="qty" name="text" type="text"  /></p>
<p><input class="qty" name="text2" type="text" /></p>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(".qty").change(function(e) {
    if(this.value != '3' && this.value != '6' && this.value != '9') {
        this.value = 0;         
        alert('You can buy only 3, 6, or 9 pieces fromn this product');
    } });

</script>
```

Comment: @Samuel, why on earth would i do that??

Comment: Why this was downoted?? Anyone care to explain the reason??

Comment: @rahul bc they are mad at me for telling them they are wrong. This answer is completely correct

Comment: Thanks, how can I add "window.onbeforeunload" in the place of the alert ?

Comment: @Bizboss -- why do u need `window.onbeforeload`?

Comment: a solution to use >window.onbeforeload in my function ??

Comment: @BizBoss  i repeat: why do u need `window.onbeforeload`?

Comment: @Neal: I need it to avoid that the user type a quantities and then go the another page, and lose all the entered values.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple elements with the same ID.

Use a classname instead.

Answer (score 1):

It only works on the first, because you're connecting the event to the ID, and using the same ID multiple times. IDs **can only be used once on a given page** in order to be useful.

Referencing element IDs in jQuery will only match the first occurrence in the DOM - this is how they work. **Use a class instead.**

Answer (score 1):

Try giving all the text boxes unique ids.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your use of the `id` attribute.

An `id` is unique. Therefore only ONE element on the page can have the id `qty`.

Use `class` instead and then all three can have `class='qty'`.

And change this to $('this')

Comment: remove that last part, and this is a fully correct answer and deserves a `+1`

Comment: No. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this - `this == $('this')[0]` be careful of this. When dealing with jQuery ALWAYS use `$('this')`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have more than one element with the same id. Use a class instead.

Also embed you change event inside document ready event.

```
$(function(){
    $("input:text.myclass").change(function(e){
        if(this.value != '3' && this.value != '6' && this.value != '9') {
            this.value = 0;         
            alert('You can buy only 3, 6, or 9 pieces fromn this product');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please explain the reason for downvote whenever you are doing it.

Answer (score 0):

ID attribute is a unique identifier of an element and you can't have duplicates within a page.  So change your IDs to class names and you'll be good to go:

```
<p><input class="qty" type="text" maxlength="1"  /></p>
<p><input class="qty" name="text" type="text"  /></p>
<p><input class="qty" name="text2" type="text" /></p>
```

Also, you have to reference the element via jQuery wrapper when you're dealing with it within jQuery context.  `this` becomes `$(this)` and `value` property becomes `val()` function call.

Change to this:

```
$(".qty").change(function(e) {
  var value = $(this).val();

    if(value != '3' && value != '6' && value != '9') {
        $(this).val(0);         
        alert('You can buy only 3, 6, or 9 pieces fromn this product');
    }
});
```

Comment: wrong wrong wrong wrong. there was nothing wrong with the way the OP did the statements

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is the solution, but in jQuery you have to use `$(this)` instead of `this`.
Then, you also have to use `.val()` instead of `value`.

So you have to use something like this:

```
$(this).val()
```

To get the value of a field, to set the value, use this:

```
$(this).val('new value')
```

**Edit:**
After you added the code:
Like, others said, you can't use an id multiple times.

**Edit 2:**
Ignore my answer, totally wrong. Excuse me.

Comment: Using just "this" and "this.value" is also correct, its just "javascript" :-)

Comment: @Ray: I'm not the downvoter, but `this.value` is perfectly valid JavaScript and is, in fact, more efficient than doing `$(this).val()`.

Comment: Yes I know, but I thought you can't use jQuery functions when using 'this'. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: it's the same thing with $(this)

Comment: @Ray: you can't do `this.val()`, as that's using a jQuery function on a DOM element.  However, `this.value` is correct.