# What is the difference between this and $(this) in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between this and $(this) in jQuery? And when should I use which?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery $(this) vs this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('p').each(function () {
  //this.id;
  //$(this).attr('id');
})
```

If you consider the function above jQuery will loop through each paragraph element on the page and will return a reference to each paragraph element by passing the 'this' variable into the anonymous function. If the 'this' variable is wrapped in the jQuery function ($(this)) then we can access all the jQuery goodness in relation to the element e.g `$(this).find('span')`. The 'this' object on it's own is just a normal Javscript DOM Object.

Answer (score 0):

`this` returns a native JavaScript object (if I call it right), `$(this)` returns a jQuery object.

```
$(this)[0] == this
```

Answer (score 0):

$() is the jQuery constructor function.

this is a reference to the DOM element of invocation.

so basically, in $(this), you are just passing the this in $() as a parameter so that you could call jQuery methods and functions.

duplicate: [jQuery: What's the difference between '$(this)' and 'this'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this)