# What is the difference between this and $(this) in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery. I want to know the difference between `this` and `$(this)`. Suppose i made a function call like this

```
$.fn.column = function() {

     var $td = this;
     var $td1 = $(this);


}; //end of  $.fn.column = function()

$('#FaqGridForm\\:faqGrid tr td').column();
```

When i use firebug, then both variables are `[td]` . So what is the difference between these two ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between this and $(this) in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965979/what-is-the-difference-between-this-and-this-in-jquery)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery $(this) vs this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this)

Comment: @Dupes, try to find the right duplicates: `this` in the context of a plugin..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a jQuery plugin, `this` points to the jQuery collection of all matched elements. Using `$(this)` in this context is obsolete, and **discouraged**.

In the context of, say, an event handler, `this` points to the DOM element from which the event is fired. `$(this)` will wrap the DOM element in a jQuery object, so that jQuery methods are available.

Code examples:

```
$.fn.plugin = function() { alert(this); };
$('selector').plugin(); //Alerts [object Object] = a jQuery object.

$('body').click(function() {
    alert(this);   // [object HTMLBodyElement]
    alert($(this));// [object Object] (a jQuery object)
});
```

Comment: @James Allardice Rory McCrossan. I just found another thing. I am suing code like this `$('#faqGrid tr td').each(function(){var $tdChildrenArray = $(this).children(); var $divChildrenArray = this.children('div');}); ` if i use `var $tdChildrenArray = this.children(); var $divChildrenArray = this.children('div');`, then i get error at after executing the line `var $tdChildrenArray = this.children();`, but if i use `var $tdChildrenArray = $(this).children();`, then there is no error. Why?

Comment: @Basit - Because in that case `this` refers to a DOM element, not a jQuery object. See my answer.

Comment: `this` in jQuery callback will **usually** point to a DOM element, so `this` should be wrapped in a jQuery object. **In a plugin** (such as in your question), `this` always points to the jQuery object with matched the selector on which the `plugin` is invoked.

Comment: Hhmmm you people mean when i used this in callback, then **this** refer to simple td, no jQuery object, i cannot use jquery methods on it, but when i used **$(this).children(), then i wrapped my td to jQuery object. Now i can use jQuery methods on it, such as children(). Is it? But in plugin case this behaves like $(td). So i can use simply this.children(). Am i right ?

Comment: @Basit Excactely, you get it :)

Comment: @Basit FYI, you can only have one accepted answer on Stack Overflow. Clicking on `Accept answer` at another answer will remove the tick from the previously accepted answer :p

Answer (score 1):

In that case, there is no real difference. Since you've extended jQuery, `this` is already an instance of jQuery and all `$(this)` does is pass it into jQuery again, which is unnecessary.

However, in cases like this:

```
$("#someElem").click(function() {
    //this is now a reference to a DOM element:
    console.log(this instanceof jQuery); //false
    console.log(this.val()); //TypeError
});
```

You often need to pass `this` into jQuery so you can use jQuery methods on it:

```
$("#someElem").click(function() {
    console.log($(this) instanceof jQuery); //true
    console.log($(this).val()); //Prints value
});
```

Comment: In your second example, `this` should be `$(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is the native DOM element in question. You can use the full gamut of DOM methods on it.

`$(this)` is the native DOM element wrapped in a jQuery object, and as such you can access all the functions jQuery provides in it's framework to amend the element as you require. You can also access the DOM element itself via the jquery object by using:

```
$("#myElement")[0]
```

*Update*

This obviously applies to writing jQuery in external functions. Rob W is correct in that your example uses a plugin, therefore `this` would refer to a jQuery object containing an element.