# $this vs $(this) in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen some discussions on SO regarding `$(this)` vs `$this` in jQuery, and they make sense to me. (See [discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this) for an example.)

But what about the snippet below, from the jQuery website plugin tutorial showing how chainability works?

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.lockDimensions = function (type) {

        return this.each(function () {

            var $this = $(this);

            if (!type || type == 'width') {
                $this.width($this.width());
            }

            if (!type || type == 'height') {
                $this.height($this.height());
            }

        });

    };
})(jQuery);
```

What does `$this` represent above?  Just when I think I have it figured out ...

Comment: `var $this = $(this);` - it's just a short-hand to not have to jQuerify `this` on every call.

Comment: In your code `$this` is a local variable that caches the `$( this )` jQuery object.

Comment: What's unclear about `var $this = $(this)`? That line of code makes `$this` equal to `$(this)`.

Comment: @CAbbott this question is **not** a dup of that one.

Comment: @CAbbott: That's not a duplicate at all. `$this !== this`

Comment: @MattBall: The Matt's are on fire today :O

Comment: I'm writing my answer... tralala... then suddenly a message pops up: "11 new answers have been posted". Huh... `:D`

Comment: `var $matt = $(matt);` @Šime, low hanging fruits are the tastiest!

Comment: @Sime You know it's an easy question when 11 other people are typing away furiously trying to be the first to answer :P

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10433014/601179) about the cost of `$(this)`

Answer (score 122, accepted):

`$this` is just an ordinary variable. The `$` character is a valid character in variable names, so `$this` acts the same as any other non-reserved variable name. It's functionally identical to calling a variable `JellyBean`.

Comment: Usually you name $vars when they are jQuery objects, so you remember they are $ and not simple JavaScript objects.

Answer (score 69):

You usually use `var $this = $(this);` to avoid creating a new jQuery object more often than necessary. In case of the code below you only create one object instead of two/four. It is completely unrelated to chainability.

You could also call it `that`, `$thi$` or anything else (don't use the latter one though, it's ugly :p) as `$` is just a simple character in JavaScript, exactly like a-z are.

Comment: +1 [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10433014/601179) about the cost of `$(this)`

Answer (score 36):

`this` in javascript (usually) represents a reference to the object that invoked the current function.  This concept is somewhat fuzzied a bit by jQuery's attempts to make the use of `this` more user friendly within their [**`.each()`**](http://api.jquery.com/each/) looping stucture.

***outside*** the `.each()`, `this` represents the jQuery object that `.lockDimensions` is invoked by.

***inside*** the `.each()` it represents the current iterated DOM object.

Generally the purpose of storing `$(this)` in a local variable is to prevent you from calling the jQuery function `$()` **multiple times**, caching a *jQueryized* `this` should help efficiency if you have to use it multiple times.

`$` is simply a valid variable name character and is used as the first character of a variable name *usually* to queue the programmer that it is a jQuery object already (and has the associated methods/properties available).

This question is actually unrelated to chain-ability, but to maintain chain-ability you should return `this` so that other function calls can be added, and maintain the meaning of `this` in those calls as well.

Answer (score 14):

you may have overlooked this line:

```
var $this = $(this);
```

Here, `$this` is just a variable that holds the value of `$(this)`. You can use it interchangeably with `$(this)` with the benefit that you aren't doing the same lookup over and over.

Answer (score 12):

`$this` is simply a local variable, named that way to remind you of `$(this)`.  It saves the work of creating the jQuery version of `this`, and you can use it a number of times.

Answer (score 10):

`$this` is just a local copy of `this` wrapped in jQuery.

In the long term, keeping a local copy rather than wrapping `this` each time it is needed is much more efficient.

Comment: You are right, instead of invoking a function all the time to get the reference, a cached copy is better choice.

Answer (score 10):

`$this = $(this)` is a way to cache the jQuery object. It is expensive to run the jQuery function each time, so storing the output allows you to re-use the selector over and over again without calling jQuery function again.

Answer (score 10):

```
 $this = $(this)
```

which means that you are assigning the current object to a variable named `$this`. It is not a keyword.

> It is just a variable name.

Answer (score 9):

It just fills `$this` variable with `$(this)`, so you do not have to lookup for `$(this)` element every call. It has better performance

```
var $this = $(this);
```

Answer (score 7):

It's quite simple: `$this = $(this)`. It's just a shorthand used in the scope of the inner function. The dollar sign is just a character in this case, it doesn't refer to jQuery at all. It might just as well have been named `_this` or `xthis`, the `$` is just a reminder of what the variable contains.

It may seem pointless, but it eliminates three redundant method invocations (the `$()` function isn't free) so it is most likely used there for performance reasons.

Answer (score 7):

Inside `$.fn.lockDimensions`, `this` is the jQuery object that had `lockDimensions` called on it.

Inside the `.each`, `this` now references the DOMElement in the current iteration of the loop.  `$(this)` wraps the DOMElement in a jQuery object, and `var $this = $(this);` is just saving `$(this)` in a variable called `$this`, so the jQuery constructor doesn't need to be called multiple times (if you were to use `$(this)` instead).

Answer (score 7):

`$` sign is usually used  before variable names in JavaScript to differentiate between general value and jQuery object. So here `$this` just gets the value of `$(this)` which returns jQuery object of `this`. `$` is just a part of valid variable name.

Answer (score 4):

`$this` is a variable named `$this` containing a reference to `$(this)`. A bit pointless IMO.

Comment: Pointless? It eliminates creating 4 separate jquery objects of the same thing.

Comment: @Andrew, surely someone called Spender does not care about spending more CPU cycles than necessary.

Comment: Yep. Is that a problem though? Until it's measurably problematic, it ain't a problem.

Comment: It also eliminates 18 chars from the minified file.

Comment: @spender, go measure it and restore your honor! :)

Comment: I have none. It's Monday. Ask me again tomorrow!

Answer (score 4):

I want to jump in here, even though I do not have expert jQuery skills.

Countless times I see lines of code or concepts similar to:

```
var $this = $(this);
```

So I do a rewrite of it similar to:

```
var $jims_this = $(this);
```

And test it. Also I do this to clear up any confusion I might have.

Here is another example of similar poorly explained code:

```
 <style>
    a.a { font-weight: bold; }
 </style>
```

Next, add the addClass call to your script:

```
  $("a").addClass("a");
```

This does work but it is confusing. It could have been written as:

```
<style>
a.my_bold_class { font-weight: bold; }
</style>

 $("a").addClass("my_bold_class");
```

Jim

Answer (score -5):

You have wandered into the realm of javascript scope and closure.

For the short answer:

```
this.bar()
```

is executed under the scope of foo, (as this refers to foo)

```
var barf = this.bar;
barf();
```

is executed under the global scope.

this.bar basically means:

execute the function pointed by this.bar, under the scope of this (foo). When you copied this.bar to barf, and run barf. Javascript understood as, run the function pointed by barf, and since there is no this, it just runs in global scope.

To correct this, you can change

```
barf();
```

to something like this:

```
barf.apply(this);
```

This tells Javascript to bind the scope of this to barf before executing it.

For jquery events, you will need to use an anonymous function, or extend the bind function in prototype to support scoping.