# get all values of fields with the same name array

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some input fields in the following format:

```
<input name='date_of_birth[month]' type='text' />
<input name='date_of_birth[day]' type='text' />
<input name='date_of_birth[year]' type='text' />
```

Is there a way to select all the values of these fields in jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$.map` method may be better in this case:

```
var dobArray = $.map($('input[type=text][name^=date_of_birth]'),function(){
  return this.value;
});
```

and to make it a date string,

```
var dobString = dobArray.join("/");
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the order of the array will be based on the DOM order of the input elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(":text[name^='date_of_birth']").each(function (){alert(this.value)});
```

http://jsbin.com/emumef/edit#javascript,html

according to @gordon about speed  - this will be faster: ( reduce extension overhead)

```
 $("input[type='text'][name^='date_of_birth']")
```

Comment: +1, note that `:text` isn't efficient selector. you should replace it with `input[type='text']`

Comment: @gdoron input type text is better ?

Comment: _"Because `:text` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :text cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use `[type="text"]` instead."_

Comment: One more thing if I may, [Though `$()` with DOM element isn't expensive](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10433014/601179), you should use `this.value` instead of `$(this).val()`.

Comment: @gordon, yeah i know . its an instinct ...:)