# Using .replace in $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, each

New to jquery. I already got this running in javascript but am switching to jquery so I can use `.each`. Is there some special rule preventing me from using JavaScripts `.replace` inside jQuerys `.each`?

```
    var jse_sanitized_title = "";
    var jse_article_title = "";

    var jse_article_titles = $('.jse_article_title');

    $.each(jse_article_titles, function(i) {

    jse_article_title = jse_article_titles[i].innerHTML;

            //error for this says jse_article_titles[i].replace is not a function
    jse_sanitized_title = jse_article_titles[i].replace(/ /g,"_");

})
```

EDIT: The purpose of the replace is to replace spaces with underscores.

Comment: `jse_article_titles[i]` is a DOM Element, not a string.

Comment: You override the string in each loop! what are you trying to do?

Comment: Instead of `$.each(jse_article_titles`, you can do `jse_article_titles.each(`.

Comment: See [my updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10588681/601179) please.

Comment: You can simply use `.text` and update all the matching selector. See DEMO >> http://jsfiddle.net/skram/WhJGG/ << [Updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10588678/297641)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you mean:

```
    $.each(jse_article_titles, function(i) {

    jse_article_title = jse_article_titles[i].innerHTML;

            //error for this says jse_article_titles[i].replace is not a function
    jse_sanitized_title = jse_article_title .replace(/ /g,"_");
    jse_article_titles[i].innerHTML = jse_sanitized_title;

})
```

If you have not already declared `jse_article_title`, put a var here, like:

```
var jse_article_title = jse_article_titles[i].innerHTML;
```

Note that you have to reassign it at the end.  Finally, there are no special rules like this. jQuery is just a library.

Comment: My mistake. I did declare all variables in my code but I forgot to include them in my example. You get the check.

Answer (score 3):

```
$.each(jse_article_titles, function() {
    jse_article_title = this.innerHTML;
    jse_sanitized_title = jse_article_title.replace(/ /g,"_");
});
```

**After the update, it looks like you want to do something like this:**

```
$('.jse_article_title').each(function(){
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(/ /g,"_");
});
```

There is another way with jQuery:

```
$('.jse_article_title').html(function(index, old){
    return old.innerHTML.replace(/ /g,"_");
});
```

Comment: +1 for .html() method.  That seems like the most appropriate way to do it the "jquery way".

Comment: If I was replacing with underscores then putting the string right back where I got it from this would be the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

> > EDIT: The purpose of the replace is to replace spaces with underscores.

Updated to use .text() function to set replace all `spaces` with `_`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/WhJGG/)

```
$('.jse_article_title').text(function () {
    return this.innerHTML.replace(/ /g, '_');
});
```

---

May be you need

```
jse_sanitized_title = jse_article_title.replace(/ /g,"_"); 
//using the jse_article_title
```

or

```
jse_sanitized_title = jse_article_titles[i].innerHTML.replace(/ /g,"_");
```

or Using jQuery,

```
jse_sanitized_title = $(this).text().replace(/ /g, "_");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.each(jse_article_titles, function() {

    jse_article_title = $(this).html();

    jse_sanitized_title = jse_article_title.replace(/ /g,"_");

})
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining why? Is it because it's an unnecessary abstraction that does the same thing?

Comment: @LittleBigBot: Because using the native DOM properties is *slightly* faster than calling the jQuery function to do that for you.

Comment: @Vega. Roket, you're right... http://stackoverflow.com/q/10433014/601179 slightly

Answer (score 0):

To do it the way you were trying (with innerHTML) you need to reference the node with get()...you'd need to do this:

```
jse_article_titles.get(i).innerHTML
```

However, you should be able to shorten that a bit.

```
$('.jse_article_title').each( function() {
    $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/ /g,"_") );
});

// or

$('.jse_article_title').each( function() {
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(/ /g,"_");
});

// whichever floats your boat
```

[EDIT]: Sorry, I was wrong about needing .get().  jse_articles_titles[i] is perfectly valid as long as the number is not negative, which is unlikely.