# jQuery $(this) optimization

Tags: jquery, optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the cost of '$(this)'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433014/what-is-the-cost-of-this)

I constantly see in some developers code where `$(this)` may exist 3-5 times referring to the same dom node.  I'm wondering at what point this is worth optimizing and storing in a variable like `var el = $(this);` ?

Does anyone know of a good reliable source for documentation on the performance of this?

Comment: well the advantages of caching doesn't need support of any documentation IMO...

Comment: tbh, 3-4 times is not going to be a rip off.. coz `this` is available in local scope..  but always better to have cached.. I would cache more complicated selectors and based on their usage..

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433014/what-is-the-cost-of-this/

Comment: I bet if you ran a test comparison running 1000 iterations on the same function, there'd be less than 10 ms of difference. So if you're doing one iteration at a time... In practice it'll be around the same, it's only a matter of theory and coding style IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have to use it more than once, cache it. IMHO, why keep calling the DOM for something?

Note: I recommend adding a `$` before the variables that are actually jquery DOM elements. It makes it easier to keep track of what the variable really is.

Answer (score 5):

I use `var $this = $(this);`

This article provides performance analysis. You'll save 1 second after 10,000 calls :)
http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/06/19/speed-up-the-jquery-code-selectors-cache/

Comment: I think this (no pun intended) has become somewhat of a convention

Answer (score 2):

If you cache it in a variable it is also less to type but can also be optimized by minifiers since `$(this)` cannot be minified while a local variable referring to `$(this)` will probably be minified to one character

Answer (score -2):

this means the element it just tagger an event.

```
$("input").click(function(){
  $(this)// this refer to the input element that you click
})
```

when we need to store this element, we use a variable to store it.
so the el of var el = $(this) also means the input element.