# prependTo many elements with the same class to their parent div?

Tags: jquery

I was trying this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".qa-a-count").appendTo(".qa-q-item-main");
});
```

But there are a lot of `.qa-a-count` and `.qa-q-item-main` divs. They end up being appened to each other. How can I do it so that they only append to their parent div (`.qa-q-item-main div`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.qa-a-count').each(function() {
   // .parent() if this is a direct child of `qa-q-item-main`
   $(this).appendTo($(this).closest('.qa-q-item-main')); 
});
```

This will go through each of `.qa-a-count` and append to its ancestor.

Comment: What about `.parent()`? I thought of using it instead of `.closest`. I might be wrong just want to know the reason behind `.closest`

Comment: @Ajinkya. closest will find the element if it's its "ancestor" not just "parent".

Comment: @Ajinkya if `.qa-a-count` is a direct child of `.qa-q-item-main`, then yes use `parent`, since I didn't know your markup, the safest I could go is to use `closest`

Comment: @NiftyDude: I think OP wants to append it to ONLY parents.

Comment: @Ajinkya. No, he want to append `$('.qa-a-count')` only to it's ancestor.

Comment: @gdoron: I think I got confused by this line `How can I do it so that they only append to their parent div`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".qa-a-count").each(function (){
    // append this- (the current ".qa-a-count") 
    // to it's closest ".qa-q-item-main" element.
    $(this).appendTo($(this).closest(".qa-q-item-main"));
});
```

Or cache `$(this)`:

```
$(".qa-a-count").each(function (){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.appendTo($this.closest(".qa-q-item-main"));
});
```

But it's not that big performance boost if you're iterating a huge number of elements.
[What is the cost of '$(this)'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10433014/601179)