# Searching many div's attributes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#div_search').keypress(function() {
    var search_term = $(this).val();
    $('.ticker_list').children('div').each(function() {
        var search_value = $(this).attr('search_term');
        if (search_value.indexOf(search_term) >= 0) {
            $(this).show();
        }
        else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});​
```

This is really slow, which makes sense since its running through 500 divs and searching each  'search_term' attribute to see if inputed search term is in the attr. Is there a better or faster way to do this? I am even interested for better search mechanisms.

I can modify the DOM, as needed as well.

**EDIT**
Sorry I should have mentioned that say the search term is "hello today johnny", the term "hello", "today" and "johnny" would have to return true, this is why I was using indexOf in the script above.

Comment: do all 500 divs actually _have_ that attribute?

Comment: You could hold and update an array in your script which holds the data you want to compare.

Comment: How can this question be off-topic? people with more reputation the knowledge...

Comment: Why are you not putting this data in javascript objects? It will be infinitely faster

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a simple CSS selector:

```
$(".ticker_list > div[search_term*="+search_term+"]")
```

You may need to escape `search_term` though, depending on what it may contain.

Comment: It would be also a good idea to add single quotes around `search_term`

Comment: This runs about the same code but in jQuery, how is this different?

Comment: @gdoron that doesn't suddenly make the performance problem go away though... well it could.. I'm making a jsperf anyway :P

Comment: I just put that `$` because it was in the question and I couldn't be bothered to type `document.querySelectorAll` instead. Normally I would though. This time I was in a rush.

Comment: @Esailija. What about the jsperf? result please... :)

Comment: @gdoron http://jsperf.com/queryselector-search-engine Note that I removed hide and show from loops because queryselector doesn't do that. (And it's not necessary even in the final solution)

Answer (score 1):

```
var search_term = this.value;
$('.ticker_list > div[search-term*="' search_term + '"]').show();
```

**Notes:**

- You better use `data-*` attributes to store "meta-data" for DOM elements, not creating your own attributes.
- Don't overuse jQuery! you can get input value with `this.value` instead of `$(this).val()`.
- If it's an expensive operation, you will get a performance boost moving from the `keypress` event to `change` or at least `keyup` event.
- If you need to improve your code even more, cache `$(this)`, [it can speed up you code a bit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10433014/601179).

Comment: @NoviceCoding. I saw your's update, I don't think your code working... are you sure it's searching for _hello\today\johnny_ can you produce a demo at http://jsFiddle.net?

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume this is faster ?

```
$('#div_search').on('keypress', function(){
       var search_term = this.value,
           elems = document.getElementsByClassName('ticker_list')[0].children;
       for (i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
           var search_value = elems[i].getAttribute('search_term');
           elems[i].style.display = (search_value.indexOf(search_term) != -1?'block':'none');
       }
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/dZQhL/)

Answer (score 0):

I made a jsperf [here](http://jsperf.com/queryselector-search-engine)

Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/C9m2K/2/

Making some small optimizations such as not hiding or showing elements in a loop improved your speed a little,
but still storing the search terms in javascript object was a lot faster.

You can build it like so:

```
var searchArray = $('.ticker_list').children('div').map( function( elem ){
    return {
        value: $(this).attr( "search_term" ),
        elem: this
    };
}).toArray();
```

You should also not toggle hide and show in the loop, if a search term only matches once, then you are calling hide
499 times when you could have just hidden the previously shown elements.

```
$('#div_search').keyup( function() {
    var previouslyShown = [],
        i, len = searchArray.length;

    return function(e) {
        var cur,
            searchTerm = $(this).val();

        $( previouslyShown ).hide();
        previouslyShown = [];
        for( i = 0; i < len; ++i ) {
            cur = searchArray[i];

            if( cur.value.indexOf( searchTerm ) >= 0 ) {
                $( cur.elem ).show();
                previouslyShown.push( cur.elem );
            }
        }

    };
}());
```