# Is it good practice to use variables instead of $(this)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the cost of '$(this)'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433014/what-is-the-cost-of-this)

In terms of both performance and readability is it good practice to name variables instead of using `$(this)`?

An example would be

```
$(".element").click(function() {

    var elem = $(this);

    //Examples
    elem.addClass("example");
    console.log( elem.attr("id") );

}):
```

Comment: @VisioN I did not see that question whilst searching, I would be fine with voluntary deletion if people agree.

Comment: I use `_this=$(this);` rather `elem=$(this);`, I feel easy to write code in that way.

Comment: Use `$this = $(this);` or `$elem = ...` instead of `elem`. Code becomes more readable when you're consistently prefixing jQuery-objects with `$`.

Comment: http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is. Since `$(this)` essentially is a pretty expensive function call triggering a Dom-Search you repeat it everytime you call `$(this)` while with `var elem = $(this);` you have the function-call  once and store the result in a variable.

Actually it's much more expensive when passing selectors to the function than passing an DOM-Element like `this`. So caching `this` will have a very tiny effect only, while caching something like `$("#foo[name|='bar']")` will really matter.

I prefer prepending the `$` to the variable name so that it's obvious that you have a jQery Object here.

```
$this = $(this);
```

Now `$this` has no significant drawback from the point of readability while having the performance advantage. Also it can be minified by compressors to a single letter variable, while `$(this)` can't.

Comment: I think, there will be no noticeable difference.

Comment: @Dev It's less noticable for actual DOM_Elements and very noticable for selectors.

Comment: That's for performance.  For readability, I think it depends on the context: when you're doing two unrelated things to $(this), I think it's more readable to specify $(this) each time - but when it's more relevant that all of the things are done to the same element, the variable makes more conceptual sense.

Comment: @Brilliand I normally use `$<name>` for cached jQuery Objects, so `$this` is pretty obvious I think.

Comment: @Christoph - That makes sense.  The extra line of code might still cost some readability, though (which I hadn't thought of when I made my previous comment).

Comment: well, per se you don't need a new line, as you could write `$this = $(this).doStuff().doMoreStuff()` since the returnvalue of any jQuery function always is the object itself. (Except selector functions of course, which may alter the resultset)

Answer (score 0):

I would personally prefer to cache the reference to variable that remain unchanged, no matter how efficient the search in jQuery is implemented. Anyhow referring variable is faster.