# What's the difference between $(this) and $("#id")?

Tags: jquery, selector, this, each

Inside an `$.each()` loop, there is one specific case that I don't understand why is failing.

When I do an if statement that says something like this (my specific example, only without the real attribute names)

```
if(($(this).attr("some-attribute")))
```

it always returns false, whether or not the attribute exists.

But if i first get the id of this element and then check for the attribute without the "this" keyword, it works okay.

```
var id = $(this).attr("id");
if(($("#"+id).attr("some-attribute")))
```

This works fine and it does return the correct value.

Comment: Could you give some context as to when/how to reproduce this issue, such as in a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I don't mean to be pedantic, and it's probably filler text, but if your attribute has a space in it that's not a valid attribute.  Can you post the actual code, or edit [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jimschubert/n69jt/)?

Answer (score 6):

`$(this)` Doesn't query the DOM, it just wraps the javascript DOM element with a jQuery object.

`$('#id')` Does query the DOM.

I suggest you reading [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10433014/601179)

Comment: Even though this answers the question title, the actual problem seems a bit different.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté. The real code is missing, he's probably having a typo error, as the scenario he describes is **impossible** as I see it.

Comment: @gdoron That's exactly I meant. `=]`

Comment: Well, i have no idea what to tell you guys. I am unable to reproduce the issue anymore, it seems to work both ways now. Maybe indeed it was a typo or just a clash with other parts of code that i didn't notice... Sorry to waste everyone's time