# jquery multiple toggle on IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, slidetoggle

im facing issues with multiple toggling on IE. it works fine with all other browser except IE (-_-). below is a abstract of my code.basically im **only** able to get an popup alert when i clicked on the first hyperlink. there were no popup when i clicked on subsequent links

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

$("a#toggleFruitSlideBox").click(function() {
          alert($(this).text());
      return false;
  });
});

<div id="bodykit_slidebox">
<div style="padding:5px 0px 0px 5px;">
    <a id="toggleFruitSlideBox" href="#" class="nav2">apple</a>
    <a id="toggleFruitSlideBox" href="#" class="nav2">orange</a>
    <a id="toggleFruitSlideBox" href="#" class="nav2">DURIAN</a>
    <a id="toggleFruitSlideBox" href="#" class="nav2">papaya</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have multiple elements with the same `id` it is an invalid HTML!

Check my answer here:
[jQuery id selector works only for the first element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11114622/601179)

The only difference between your code and the code in the other question is that you use a bad selector:

```
$("a#toggleFruitSlideBox")
```

Which cause jQuery not to use the `document.getElementById`, so this is why it works in other browsers.

From the jQuery docs:

> For id selectors, jQuery uses the JavaScript function document.getElementById(), which is extremely efficient. When another selector is attached to the id selector, such as h2#pageTitle, jQuery performs an additional check before identifying the element as a match.

Remove the duplicated id and use other selector like the class selector.

Comment: hi gdorori, thank you very much. it works. i learnt something new today. *kudos*

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is that all your Id's are the same. Id's are supposed to be unique. Either use a class or just use the a selector if you don't care if it fires on all a tags.

Comment: hey nathan, tks for pointing that out. you are right. i have to use the class selector instead. it is working now.