# Is there a performance gain from caching $(this)?

Tags: jquery, performance

I often use `$(this)` inside jQuery event handlers and never cache it. If I'll do

```
var $this = $(this);
```

and will use variable instead of the constructor, will my code get any significant extra performance?

---

JS Perf test to measure the performance gain from this optimization: http://jsperf.com/jquery-this-caching

Comment: That depends on how frequently it is used. `$(this)` constructs a new jQuery object, and everything that goes with it. Generally if you are going to use `$(this)` more than once in a block of code, you should cache it. Especially if you are doing it in a loop.

Comment: It's always going to be faster to cache `$(this)` in a var. It's micro-optimization to be sure. You definitely need to be caching any selectors, because that has much bigger implications.

Comment: If you evaluate it 100 times within the same call stack, you may get 1, or 2 milliseconds slower execution.

Comment: More good answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433014/what-is-the-cost-of-this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A ***teeny tiny miniscule imperceptible one***, yes. Significant? No.

Every time you do `$(this)`, it results in several function calls and a couple of memory allocations. The function calls are neither here nor there (even on IE6, I was [surprised to learn](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2012/02/foreach-and-runtime-cost.html)), but the memory churn could add up on browsers that don't handle memory management very well. Most modern ones do.

I always save the result to a variable, because I just don't like calling functions and allocating objects needlessly. And it saves typing those parens. :-)

Comment: I just apply the same rule I do in all my other programming.  If I'm calling the same function more than once within a function, I cache the result so I don't have to call it more than once.  `$()` is a function call.  Been using that as a guideline for 30 years.

Comment: @jfriend00: Yeah, me too (and a surprisingly similar period of time...).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, because everytime you do `$(this)` you create a new jquery object.
But you won't get a significant performance, just if you do it more than 1000x

And it's a good practice to cache objects used more than once.