# Difference between $(“someElement”) and jquery object from the argument of a function

Tags: jquery

I have the following lines of code

```
$("*[class]").each(function (index, elem)
{
    console.log("Element: " + elem.tagName + " " + $(elem).prop("className"));
});
```

What I can't understand is that what's the difference between `elem` and `$(elem)`.
Isn't `elem`  already a jJuery object? if yes then why do we need to put it again like `$(elem)` in the `console.log` argument to get the property className.
Why can't we directly do something like `elem.prop("className")`.

Comment: I think you're confused about the line between Javascript and Jquery.

Comment: `elem` is a dom element, not a jQuery object. the jQuery object does contain the dom element, you can access it with .get(0) or [0]

Comment: JQuery objects can use JQuery functions (like `.prop('classname')`)... normal elements don't have access to those (unless you convert them).

Answer (score 3):

First, there existed the DOM. This is the browser's way of understanding an HTML document once it has been parsed. The browser natively understands a certain way of accessing and interacting with the elements.

However, these are fairly limited and *very* verbose. They do not make it easy to write or to read.

This is why jQuery was created.

When you build a jQuery object with `$()`, it creates a new object that "wraps" the native DOM object, and indeed often is used to wrap multiple DOM objects and to work on them together. There are a whole load of functions that are available and which do all the verbose leg work for you, so your code is easy both to write and to read. Nothing new is possible with jQuery, but it's a lot quicker to write and to read.

In this case, `elem` is the native DOM object. When iterating over the collection with `each`, jQuery doesn't automatically convert DOM objects into jQuery objects. This is for two main reasons. First, you don't always need the jQuery object. If, for instance, all you want to do is get the element's `tagName` property, you can just do `elem.tagName`. Second, creating a jQuery object is computationally expensive. It could slow your script down significantly.

So if you want to get a jQuery object, you need to use the jQuery constructor yourself.

Comment: +1 Exellent answer! just about that `$(element)` is expensive: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10433014/601179

Comment: @gdoron Well, it's expensive compared to not doing it at all... http://jsperf.com/jquery-constructor-in-an-each-function

Comment: But what if i do something like var newElem = $("<div class = 'dcell'/>").append("<img src='/Content/Images/x.jpeg'/>").append("<label for = 'x'>X:</label>") .append("<input name ='x' value ='0' required/>"); Is the resulting object "newElem" is an element or a jquery object.

Comment: @user2913184 A jQuery object. You created a jQuery object, and it will continue to be a jQuery object unless you ask for something else! [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6974582/417562) may be of interest.

Comment: @lonesomeday, I'm not saying it doesn't have a cost, I'm saying it's not **that** expensive. Of course if you can avoid writing useless code you should do it, especially inside loops.

Comment: @gdoron Indeed. I'm just explaining why jQuery provides the DOM element, rather than creating a jQuery selection automatically.

Comment: does it make sense to do something like
var newElem = $("<div class = 'dcell'/>").append($("<img src='/Content/Images/x.jpeg'/>"));
or append method should only be passed html elements not converted jquery object.

Comment: @user2913184 That makes sense, but it's unnecessary. All you need to do is pass the HTML string: jQuery will do the rest. It's all in the [API reference](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

Answer (score 1):

The `each` function parameter is the native DOM element, not the jQuery object wrapping that native DOM element.

Note that this behavior is true for all the jQuery functions that I know, `val`, `attr`, `map` ... ... always the parameter is the DOM element, not the jQuery object.

Also you can get to that native element with the `this` keyword.

---

Native element is an elements implementing the [Element interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element)
jQuery object is simply an object wrapping a set of native elements( zero to N elements).
jQuery objects have more robust and easy API such as `.html()` while native elements have awkward API, many examples for that...

jQuery object has `prop` while native elements have just the property...
`$(element).prop('id')` VS `element.id`
This example is bad, as usually the native approach is **not** simpler. `:)`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply gordon, will appreciate if you elaborate your statement a little more.

Comment: @user2864740 thats what i assume .