# jquery $(this).id return Undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have two asp radio buttons on a page that are placed in a `updatepanel`. I wrote a click event for them with jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".inputs").click(function () {
         alert($(this).id);
    });
});
```

But it returns Undefined. What is the problem?

```
EDIT:

        alert(" or " + $(this).attr("id"));
alert(this.id);
```

These two lines return `null`!

Comment: Always use console.log(); It Would Be Much Easier. In your example you can use: console.log(this); And it's show all data (id,className etc...)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Another option (just so you've seen it):

```
$(function () {
    $(".inputs").click(function (e) {
         alert(e.target.id);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 134):

`$(this)` and `this` aren't the same. The first represents a jQuery object wrapped around your element. The second is just your element. The `id` property exists on the element, but not the jQuery object. As such, you have a few options:

1. Access the property on the element directly:

   `this.id`
2. Access it from the jQuery object:

   `$(this).attr("id")`
3. Pull the object out of jQuery:

   `$(this).get(0).id; // Or $(this)[0].id`
4. Get the `id` from the `event` object:

   When events are raised, for instance a click event, they carry important information and references around with them. In your code above, you have a click event. This event object has a reference to two items: `currentTarget` and `target`.

   Using `target`, you can get the `id` of the element that raised the event. `currentTarget` would simply tell you which element the event is currently bubbling through. These are not always the same.

   `$("#button").on("click", function(e){ console.log( e.target.id ) });`

Of all of these, the best option is to just access it directly from `this` itself, unless you're engaged in a series of nested events, then it might be best to use the `event` object of each nested event (give them all unique names) to reference elements in higher or lower scopes.

Comment: Obviously a popular enough question that this was the number one search result when I googled "$(this).id in jquery".  And your answer was right on and helped me out.  I went with the .attr() method and it worked like a charm.  Thanks!

Comment: @Pier indeed this is the best answer, but not the only one that is correct.

Comment: @yeyo But this is the more useful, more elegant and more complete answer. It even includes as its option #4 the answer that is listed in the "correct" answer. OP should set this to the correct answer.

Answer (score 10):

Hiya **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/LYTbc/

This is a reference to the DOM element, so you can wrap it directly.

`attr` API: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

The .attr() method gets the attribute value for only the first element in the matched set.

Have a nice one, cheers!

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".inputs").click(function () {
        alert(this.id);
        
        alert(" or " + $(this).attr("id"));
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 4):

`$(this)` is a jQuery object that is wrapping the DOM element `this` and jQuery objects don't have `id` properties. You probably want just `this.id` to get the `id` attribute of the clicked element.

Answer (score 3):

use this actiion

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var a = this.id;

alert (a);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this : is the DOM Element
$(this) : Jquery objct, which wrapped with Dom Element, you can check this answer also   [this vs $(this)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389944/this-vs-this-in-jquery)

try like this  [Attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).  Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".inputs").click(function () {
         alert(" or " + $(this).attr("id"));

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $(".inputs").click((e) => {
         alert($(e.target).attr('id'))
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.attr('id')` to get the `id` of an element.

```
$(".fichier").bind('click', function(){      
     alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```