# get ID of clicked control

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Using jQuery I'm trying to get the id of control, which I clicked (radiobutton). I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578566/jquery-this-id-return-undefined) and tried almost everything from there:

```
alert($(this).get(0).id);
alert($(this).id);
alert($(this).attr('id'));
alert(this.id);
```

But I'm always getting: `Undefined`

I just don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

**UPDATED:**

Radiobuttons is generated dynamically in code behind by C#:

```
controlToReturn = new RadioButton
                    {
                        ID = controlId
                    };
                    ((RadioButton)controlToReturn).Text = text;
                    ((RadioButton)controlToReturn).Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(value));
                    ((RadioButton)controlToReturn).GroupName = groupName;
                    ((RadioButton)controlToReturn).CssClass = cssClass;
                    ((RadioButton)controlToReturn).Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                    ((RadioButton)controlToReturn).Attributes.Add("onclick", "Show();");
```

and function in ASPX:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function Show() {

             if ($(this).cheked = true) {

                 console.log(this);
                 alert($(this).get(0).id);
                 alert($(this).id);
                 alert($(this).attr('id'));
                 alert(this.id);               
             }        
         }
     </script>
```

I know radiobutton has id, I checked generated HTML.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code? `this.id` and `$(this).attr('id')` should work, so there's a problem somewhere else in your code. HTML too please.

Comment: Does the element have an id attribute? That code needs to be inside a click event handler by the way. Here is an demonstration of what you are trying to do http://jsfiddle.net/gtaKc/1/

Comment: What happens if you `alert(this)`? Or, better, `console.log(this)`?

Comment: @ahren +1 and `$(this).get(0).id` should work too.

Comment: Of course it's inside click event handler.
---
Big edit, couldn't answer faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*C#:*

```
((RadioButton)controlToReturn).Attributes.Add("onclick", "Show(this);");
```

*JavaScript:*

```
function Show(radio) {
    if (radio.checked) {
        alert(radio.id);               
    }        
}
```

Comment: okay, it works this way. I just thought that I can get current control using 'this'.

Comment: @Alex Yes, you can do it. Set in C# the following: `.Add("onclick", "Show");` and in JavaScript: `function Show() { if (this.checked) alert(this.id); }`.

Comment: Actually I did this if ($(this).cheked = true) {alert(this.id);};, it didn't work.

Comment: @Alex Pay attention that in JavaScript the *equals to* comparison is `==` or `===` (strict). Moreover, `$(this).cheked` is invalid, since there is no `cheked` property in jQuery object. Use either `this.checked` or `$(this).prop("checked")`.

Comment: yes, you're right it was cheked, not checked, so it was not correct.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is `this` has no context within your function and is in fact the `window` itself.

You would need to modify both the output html to provide context as an argument:

```
 ((RadioButton)controlToReturn).Attributes.Add("onclick", "Show(this);");
```

and change the function `Show`:

```
function Show(el) {
    /* for jQuery use $(el) */
    if(el.checked) {
        alert(el.id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To attach a click-listener and alert the ID, your code would look something like this:

```
​$(function () {
    $("input[type='radio']").on("click", function () {
        alert(this.id);            
    });
});​
```

A working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SSBnV/1/

Comment: `$(this).prop("id")` does the same as `this.id` but slower.

Comment: @Vision I did question you initially, but it seems you're right :). Here's a jsPerf (although it uses `attr`) http://jsperf.com/el-attr-id-vs-el-id/19

Comment: @mattytommo There is no need in jsperf here to understand it :) Creating jQuery object out of DOM element and executing its method worth much more than getting DOM object property.

Comment: @VisioN Agreed, but it only takes one mis-informed person to question your logic :)