# Why does the ".id" method not work in this jQuery code?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
var thisTable = $(this).closest('table').id;
```

Firebug shows:

```
$(this).closest('table').id -> Undefined
```

However, the following does work:

```
$(this).closest('table').attr('id')  -> "myTable"
$(this).closest('table').prop('id')  -> "myTable"
```

Is the .id method not supported after jQuery's selectors like .closest?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578566/jquery-this-id-return-undefined) helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.id` is not method, but property. jQuery does not have it, js has. So you need to do `$(this).closest('table')[0]` to get js object, than `$(this).closest('table')[0].id`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="id-of-tbl">
  <tr>
    <td><button onClick="console.log($(this).closest('table')[0].id)">Get ID</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```