# Get selected item from select menu in jQuery/jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery Mobile code like this:

```
<select name="selectmenu1" id="selectmenu1">
                        <option value="o1">
                           a
                        </option>
                        <option value="o2">
                            b
                        </option>
                        <option value="o3">
                            c
                        </option>
                        <option value="o4">
                            d
                        </option>
                    </select>
```

Now I want to get the selected value after the user changed the selection.

How to do this with jQuery?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's very simple...

```
$("#selectmenu1").change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val(); // or this.value
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cPVpw/).

If you wanted the selected element's text node(s), use this instead...

```
$("#selectmenu1").change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).find(":selected").text();
});​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sz4QP/).

Comment: so $(this) selects the last selected element?

Comment: @gurehbgui http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389944/this-vs-this-in-jquery $(this) means current object .

Comment: Please, please, `$(this).val()` => `this.value` :). thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#selectmenu1').on('change', function(){
     alert( this.value );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Here is the right answer for Jquery Mobile device .

```js
$(document).bind( "change",'#selectmenu1', function(event, ui) {
    alert($( '#selectmenu1' ).val());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
 
    
    
<select name="selectmenu1" id="selectmenu1">
  <option value="o1">
    a
  </option>
  <option value="o2">
    b
  </option>
  <option value="o3">
    c
  </option>
  <option value="o4">
    d
  </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/5RaDB/

```
<select name="selectmenu1" id="selectmenu1">
                    <option value="o1">
                       a
                    </option>
                    <option value="o2">
                        b
                    </option>
                    <option value="o3">
                        c
                    </option>
                    <option value="o4">
                        d
                    </option>
</select>

<div id="getval" ></div>


<script>
 function displayVals() {
       var singleValues = $("select").val();
      $("#getval").html(singleValues);
  }
  $('#selectmenu1').change(function() {
      displayVals();
  });​
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this.. this is the simplest way..

```
  <select name="selectmenu1" id="selectmenu1" onchange="selectvalue(this.value)>
                        <option value="o1">
                           a
                        </option>
                        <option value="o2">
                            b
                        </option>
                        <option value="o3">
                            c
                        </option>
                        <option value="o4">
                            d
                        </option>
                    </select>
```

On JavaScript side code is ..

```
function selectvalue(value){

alert(value);

}
```