# jQuery on('click') not functioning after about 5 seconds

Tags: jquery

I have a page loaded within a page. On the original page everything works fine. However, when loaded within another page, the `.on('click')` stops functioning after about 5 seconds. It's not in a timer. There are two timers on the page, but when turned off they have no effect on the freezing of the loaded page after about 5 seconds.

I tested this in IIS and WAMP, but neither work, so I highly doubt it's the server.

Comment: Can you provide us with some code to have a look at?

Comment: Sure, one second, I'll have to upload the entire site.

Comment: Can you show just the bit of code that affects the problem? No the whole site please. And is it possible that it takes up to 5 seconds to load the page and that there just is an error? Look in your console.

Comment: How are you loading the 2nd page. Also did you check the console? Im thinking conflict. the 5 seconds maybe the time i requires to load the 2nd page. Sharing your source code maybe a good idea to move forward.

Comment: The problem is the code works fine on its own. It's just when it's on another page in a `.load()` function that it freezes after 5 seconds. So, the example code would just be `$(this).load('example.php');`

Comment: It loads the page immediately, works for about 5 seconds, and then the buttons triggered with `.on('click')` stop working. Also, in the console everything is fine. I'll work on uploading it to the internet.

Comment: Okay.. jquery's "this" is very tricky. if you are making any kind of external calls, this becomes invalid. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389944/this-vs-this-in-jquery

Comment: It's actually `$("#html_currentthread").load();` The page loads fine, so I don't think actually loading the page is the problem.

Comment: what's the core of your click function ? Are there others trigger that are frizzed or only clicks events ? There is no recursivity or what ?

Comment: It's `.on('click', function () {})` There's no recursivity. It's a simple click function. There are very similar triggers that work fine.