# Getting element values in jQuery using each

Tags: jquery, each

How can I get this value ? This not works :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/theme/js/jquery1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.Text1').click(function () {
        $('.Span1').each(function () {
            alert($('.Span1').val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

I need to get the Span1's value. What I'm doing wrong ?

Edit : Span1 elements are `<span>`, that contains text.

Comment: what are `.Span1` elements, are they inputs? as if they are `<span>` it won't have a value, perhaps you want `text()`? Adding your HTML would be helpful

Comment: No its not input, its a span, that contains text, thank you very much, text worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/6NTeK/

You are missing : `this` & use text to grab text.

- if you keen: [$this vs $(this) in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389944/this-vs-this-in-jquery)

Hope rest fits your need `:)`

**Code**

```
$('.Text1').click(function () {
    $('.Span1').each(function () {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much -this- and -text- fixed the problem.

Comment: @Mike Glad it helped. `:)` keep rocking!