# this vs $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery $(this) vs this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this)

I'm new to this and trying to get my concept right. There has been many instances of the use of "`this`" and "`$(this)`". Can someone please explain the difference and in what condition that we use the two different "this"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this

Comment: Many thanks guys! It much clearer now.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In jQuery functions, `this` most often refers to the actual DOM element you're dealing with, whereas `$(this)` returns a jQuery object that wraps the element.

In JavaScript, `this` always refers to the current scope. Many of jQuery's functions will set that scope to be the element you're working with.

For instance

```
$("#someElement").click(function() {
    this;    // the element itself
    $(this); // a jQuery wrapper-object around the element
});
```

The point is, that the jQuery object has all the jQuery functions (like `.detatch()` or `.prependTo()` etc.), while the DOM element is what the browser provides. In the example above, the element would be exactly the same as what you'd get, if you called `document.getElementById("someElement")`

Answer (score 7):

`$(this)` refers to a jquery object, `this` refers to `this` in the current scope

Answer (score 6):

`$(this)` is a jQuery object. `this` refers to the value of `this` within the current scope. You typically use `$(this)` inside a callback when you want to convert the element that triggered the event, into a jQuery object. You can do this to pretty much any DOM element, so `$(document.getElementById("#myElement"))` is also valid, and is a jQuery object that represents the DOM element with id "myElement".