# How to trigger click event on select element? (not change)

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code when I change the selection, there will be an `alert`. I am trying to make the function like when I click on the `option` then it will show an `alert`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#x").change(function() {
    alert("Haha");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="x">
  <option selected>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>
```

In the below code there is no effect when I click on the options already selected options. for example a is selected then i click a is no effect.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#x").on("option", "click", function() {
    alert("Haha");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="x">
  <option selected>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>
```

because i want to trigger event while i re-clicking the selected option.

click selection box->drop menu->click selected option->trigger event

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery select option click handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749597/jquery-select-option-click-handler)

Comment: `option` elements do not raise mouse events. Why do you need this? If you want to know the option which was selected just use `$(this).val()` within the `change` event handler

Comment: You should add closing curly bracket for the click function.

Comment: Check [How to use onClick() or onSelect() on option tag in a JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487263/how-to-use-onclick-or-onselect-on-option-tag-in-a-jsp-page/3487274#3487274)

Comment: what about `$('selector').on('click', function(){console.log('clicked');}); $('selector').trigger('click');` ?

Comment: I think you can make a customized drop down menu and bind the click event.

Comment: this can be happen in is select is multiple. in this case i am not sure.
but If multiple
 $("select option").click(function() {
    var clickedOption = $(this);
 console.log(clickedOption.text());

Comment: Thanks for all, and AJAY MARURYA you are right, although select option can't trigger in Chrome but can trigger in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"click selection box->drop menu->click selected option->trigger event"*

First of all do not use `alert()`, it prompts for an extra click you really don't need to waste your time on. Use [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log).

The following demo:

- Delegates the `click` event to `select#x`:

> **$('#x')[.on](https://api.jquery.com/on)(['click'](https://api.jquery.com/click),...**

- Once clicked, it will trigger a **`focus` event on every even click<sup>✱</sup>**:

> <sup>✱</sup> **if (cnt % 2 === 0) { $(this)[.trigger](https://api.jquery.com/trigger)('focus');}**

- `select#x` is also delegated to the `focus` event and will call `optionTrigger()`:

> **$('#x').on(['focus'](https://api.jquery.com/focus), optionTrigger);**

- `function optionTrigger()` will log the selected `<option>` index and text:

> <sup>✱</sup> **if (cnt < 2) {**...
>
> ...**[$(this)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7479331/2813224).trigger(['blur'](https://api.jquery.com/blur/)); }**
>
> **var idx = $(this)[[0]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5533784/2813224)[.selectedIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex);**
>
> **var txt = $(this)[.find](https://api.jquery.com/find)('option')[.eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq)(idx)[.text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/);**

---

### Demo

```js
var cnt = 1;

$("#x").on("click", function(e) {
  if (cnt % 2 === 0) {
    $(this).trigger('focus');
  }
  cnt++;
});

$('#x').on('focus', optionTrigger);

function optionTrigger(e) {
  if (cnt < 2) {
    $(this).trigger('blur');
  } else {
    var idx = $(this)[0].selectedIndex;
    var txt = $(this).find('option').eq(idx).text();
    console.log(idx + ': ' + txt);
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="x">
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks i mean while you choose A when you press the first time

Comment: No problem, I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried bind with select e.g.:

```
$('#x').bind('click', function(){
    console.log('Clicked') 
 });
```

If this doesn't work do tell. Thanks
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks~This will trigger the selection box clicked after that you see the drop down menu come out, if you click the selected option there will be no happened.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to execute your code while clicking on Dropdown???

If Yes, here is the code for you

https://jsfiddle.net/shoesheill/gjLyxo5d/6/

If not please leave a comment along with your requirements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#x").off().on('click',function() {
    alert("Haha");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks i need to execute the codes while i re-clicking selected option

Comment: if you find it effective voteup my answer, or accept it as your best answer it you be helpful for both of us @K2R