# $(this) and this. in the same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

The code below would invoke a function which adds the clicked name into an array. However, $(this) is calling the app object instead of the clicked text. I'm guessing I can't use $(this) and this in the same function and expect the this to be calling different things. Is there an alternative solution to this?

```
var App = function () {
this.friends = [];
};

App.prototype.addFriend = function () {
name = $(this).text();
this.friends.push(name); 
}

var app = new App();

$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on("click", ".user", function () {app.addFriend()});
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [this vs $(this)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479282/this-vs-this)

Comment: Pass the event object, and use `$(event.target)` insted of `$(this)`. Or if it's just that value you need to read, `text = event.target.value;`, an extra DOM traversing step is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the target element of the click event as an argument to `addFriend()`:

```
App.prototype.addFriend = function (item) {
name = $(item).text();
this.friends.push(name); 
}

var app = new App();

$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on("click", ".user", function (event) {app.addFriend(event.target)});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pass event object to function and take the value from it

```
var App = function () {
this.friends = [];
};

App.prototype.addFriend = function (event) {
name = $(event).target.value;
this.friends.push(name); 
}

var app = new App();

$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on("click", ".user", function (event) {app.addFriend(event)});
}
```