# is there a proper way to iterate over multiple selectors in jquery

Tags: jquery

suppose i have a `.on()` function wherein i select multiple ids

```
    $("#i, #am, #your, #father").on("click" , function(event){
    //iterate over the selectors and return tagname
       alert ( $("#i").prop("tagName")  );
       alert ( $("#am").prop("tagName") );
       alert ( $("#your").prop("tagName") );
       alert ( $("#father").prop("tagName") );
    }
```

the only method that i can think of is to alert each one separately. is there a known method for handing the `$("#i, #am, #your, #father")` as a sort of array?

Comment: won't `alert($(this).prop("tagName"));` shall do the needful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
var $groupSelection = $('#i, #am, #your, #father');

$groupSelection.on('click', function(e){
   $groupSelection.each(function(){
      alert( $(this).prop('tagName') );
   });
});
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/ZHpFa/

Answer (score 4):

Try this please:

Interesting read: [jQuery: What's the difference between '$(this)' and 'this'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this)

Also on click of any of these  chained `ids` you can use `$(this)` to get prop `tagName`

Further if you are wondering how to bind all of them to on var see here: `$foo` example: http://jsfiddle.net/6hwLS/5/

Hope this helps,

```
$("#i, #am, #your, #father").on("click" , function(event){
//iterate over the selectors and return tagname
   alert($(this).prop("tagName")  );

}
```

**further** you can also do this

```
var $foo = $("#i, #am, #your, #father");

$foo.on("click", function(event) {
    //iterate over the selectors and return tagname
    alert($(this).prop("tagName"));

}​
```

Comment: the top rated comment says `Basically every time you get a set of elements back jQuery turns it into an array`. does this mean that by calling `.on()`, it not only sets events but also returns the elements in my selector?

Comment: Hiya @user571099 cool, I reckon to understand `.on` plz read here :) http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @user571099 no probs at all, glad it helped!