# Select which radio button is selected based on Name and Value

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a pretty basic show/hide script and am basing it on which of the two radio buttons below are checked. My problem is that I can't add id's to the radio buttons, as the code is dynamically generated. Is there any way using JQuery to select which box is checked based on the combination of the name and value? Once I have that IF statement I can handle the rest, but I only know how to do it using classes or ID's.

```
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap mysql">
   <span id="mysql" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-radio radiobuttons">
      <span class="wpcf7-list-item">
         <label>
            <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Yes</span>
            &nbsp;
            <input type="radio" name="mysql" value="Yes">
         </label>
      </span>
      <span class="wpcf7-list-item">
         <label>
            <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">No</span>
            &nbsp;
            <input type="radio" name="mysql" value="No">
         </label>
      </span>
   </span>
</span>
```

So basically I am looking for something like "if the name is mysql, the value is Yes, and the radio button is checked, do X. If the name is mysql, the value is No, and the radio button is checked, do Y.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/YLesK/3/

The name attribute if same throughout so I reckon you will be fine if you check `this.value` ; otherwise, you can add this condition `$(this).prop('name') === "mysql"` ==> http://jsfiddle.net/YLesK/5/

Hope this helps, `:)`

**code**

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        if(this.value === "Yes")
            alert("Do X I am yes");
        else if (this.value === "No")
            alert("Do Y I am No");
    });

});
```

Comment: you can also do this $('input[type="radio"][name="mysql"]').click(function(){ ... to take care of the name

Comment: Perfect! Thanks tats. I will need that name attribute included, as its not the only Yes/No radio buttons. I'll pop the tick on once I have it working :)

Comment: Hiya bruv, as always `Comprehensive` +1

Comment: I'm not sure why but in my live environment I had to kick off the script with jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {. Worked perfectly after that :)

Comment: @FerdiaO'Brien Yep might be somewher in your code you are using `.noConflict` Glad it worked for you now! `:)`

Comment: Just realised I never popped on the tick. Apologies :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".wpcf7-list-item input:radio").click(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Yes"){
        alert("do yes function");
    }else{
       alert("do no function");             
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jeBFN/1/

Comment: Just for share purpose bruv: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this ; `this.value` will do the trick, `:)` have a nice read. D'uh your stuff works as well. +1 anyways.

Comment: @Tat_innit good call I'm so used to wrapping the object in the function I am binding to the event.