# why is jQuery selector property undefined within each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following code, why does the selector property work in the first instance but not the second?  Aren't they both jQuery objects?

```
<span class='tst'>span</span>​

var tst = $('.tst');
console.log(tst.selector); 
// prints '.tst'

$('.tst').each(function() { console.log(this.selector);});
// prints undefined​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this`, in the context of the `.each()` loop, is not a jQuery object, so the `selector` property is undefined.

You need to make it a jQuery object first: `$(this).selector`

However, it should be noted that the `selector` property will return an empty string while inside the `.each()` loop.

**Edit**

If you absolutely need the `selector` property within the `.each()`, one option would be to cache your selector:

```
var cached = $('.tst');

cached.each(function() { 
    console.log(cached.selector); // Will display ".tst"
});
```

​

Comment: yes, i'd tried it with $(this), but got the empty string.  is there any way to get the text within an each()?

Comment: @mix: Yes, if you want the text of each element, use `.text()`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: sorry, i mean the selector property text (in this case, '.tst')

Comment: @mix: One option would be to cache the selector (Perhaps someone else has a better idea). I'll update with an example.

Comment: Note (for OP): There are lots of ways to create jQuery objects such that the concept of `selector` doesn't make sense (e.g., by combining several other jQuery objects), so writing code that actually _needs_ to test the `selector` is generally not a good plan.

Answer (score 2):

`this != $(this)`

In your first case `tst` is a reference to the jQuery object, but in the second `this` is simply the corresponding DOM element.

Within an `.each()` loop the .selector property is not available, however. To access '.tst' you can do `$(this).attr("class")` (when you use a class selector) -- though if you already use it in the each you can just cache it in a variable before hand.

Note that this will return all of the classes for that elements, so you can parse it later if it has more than one.

The best workaround based on your exact description is this:

```
var $tst = $(".tst");
$tst.each(function() {
    console.log($tst.selector); //prints .tst
});
```

However I can't see any reason why you really need to do this.

Answer (score 1):

**Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/wA6Yv/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/a3CYR/2/

> this != $(this)

If you keen: [jQuery: What's the difference between '$(this)' and 'this'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this)

**code**

```
var tst = $('.tst');
console.log(tst.selector);
// prints '.tst'
$('.tst').each(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
// prints undefined
```