# jQuery Selector Context: this or $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

When passing a context to the selector, is it better to pass `this` or `$(this)`? I tried the latter and it worked; [the doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) mentioned the former.

```
$('.link').on('click', function () {
  $('.element', this).addClass('something');
  // or, $('.element, $(this)).addClass('something'); ?
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this

Comment: It depends on the context that your are using `this`. If you are going to call a jQuery function, `$(this).hide()` you have to use $(this). If you just need to reference the given element you can use the plain `this`. In the context you have here `$(this)` is used no differently than `this`. In fact there is probably some (minimal) overhead to convert the element to a jQuery object and then reference the element inside the wrapper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
$(this).find('.element').addClass('something');
```

`$('.element', this)` will turn into `$(this).find('.element')` internal.

Comment: @Aknosis Why? No matter you use `this` or `$(this)` as the second parameter, it will be turned into `$(this).find('.element')...`

Comment: I guess you are right, I just read the source and they both equivalent in functionality. I was thinking more in terms of the this vs $(this) question, but in the context given it makes no difference whatsoever.

Comment: From the source (1.8.2):
`return this.constructor( context ).find( selector );`