# How do I discover the DOM element that fired the event and behave accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

I am trying to have multiple `<a>` tags (or any other tag) that I want bound to the same handler. I want the handler to discover which `<a>` tag was clicked and behave accordingly.

Example:

```
<a class="menu">Item1<a>
<a class="menu">Item2<a>
<a class="menu">Item3<a>

$(".menu").click(function(){
    //...Find out which a was clicked...
    ($(a .menu).html()=='Item1)

}
```

What is the best way to go about doing this? I want this to behave in a way similar to the VirtualHosts section of Apache. Is it even possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery `$(this)` :

```
$(".menu").click(function(){
    $(this).html('Item1');
}
```

here is difference with [jQuery: What's the difference between '$(this)' and 'this'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this)

Answer (score 2):

The `this` keyword will be the element that triggered the event:

```
$(".menu").click(function(){
    var clickedItem = this;
    alert(clickedItem.innerHTML);
}
```

You can wrap that in a jQuery object if you like:

```
$(".menu").click(function(){
    var clickedItem = $(this);
    if (clickedItem.text() === 'Item1') {
        alert('It was item 1');
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to type `clickedItem.text()` or since you're only using it once: `$(this).text()`?