# getting the value of span inside div's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to iterate through all the span elements that is the children of a div:

```
 $('#recommendTextArea').children('span').each(function () {
            console.log(this.html()); 
        });
```

However I always get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLSpanElement> has no method 'html'
```

I tried changing it to text(), but it also doesn't work

Comment: could also worth a read: [jquery-this-vs-this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this :

```
console.log($(this).html());
```

You were trying to call `.html()` on DOM element, not a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $('#recommendTextArea').children('span').each(function () {
        console.log($(this).text()); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Try $(this).html() or $(this).text()

2) you could use alternatively $('#recommendTextArea').find("span") to get the spans

Answer (score 0):

[`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) is a jQuery function and must be called on a jQuery object. You can create a jQuery object from `this` by passing it to the [jQuery object](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/), like `$(this)`

In your code `this` is a `<span>` which does not have any native method called `.html()`, hence the JavaScript error.