# Append content to one div only

Tags: jquery

I am trying to append content to a specific div only without effecting the other divs.

How to append content to one div only without showing the content in other divs? 
This is a live demo of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/aGC5s/

This is jquery code:

```
$(".wrapper .button").click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $('.wrapper').append('<span>   This content will be added  </span>');
});
```

Comment: Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aGC5s/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".wrapper .button").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().append('<span>   This content will be added  </span>');
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aGC5s/7/)

Using your code:

```
$('.wrapper').append('<span>   This content will be added  </span>');
```

Append the new content to all the div with `.wrapper` class. We need to firstly get the button in the current scope of the click event using `this`. After, that we will get its parent using `$(this).parent()` and then append the new content only to that specific div.

**UPDATE**

A much better code would be using the [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) here:

```
$(".wrapper .button").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.wrapper').append('<span>This content will be added</span>');
});
```

Now, `closest('.wrapper')` will get the first element that matches the *.wrapper* selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree and making sure non-immediate descendants are not selected.

Comment: This assumes `.wrapper` is always the parent, but the selector used allows non-immediate descendants.

Comment: ya, better is to use .parents().first() or closest() for less static html code

Comment: There is one issue, once I have clicked the button twice or more the content keeps repeating example(This content will be added This content will be added This content will be added). You can test it by click the button more than once. 
http://jsfiddle.net/aGC5s/7/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$(this)` to get the source element and use `closest()` to get the parent with class `wrapper` of source of event.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aGC5s/14/)**

```
$(".wrapper .button").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.wrapper').append('<span>   This content will be added  </span>');
});
```

Comment: but the clicked wrapper is not always :eq(0)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).closest('.wrapper').append('<span>This content will be added</span>');
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/aGC5s/6/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/aGC5s/3/

```
  $(".wrapper .button").click(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      $(this).closest('.wrapper').append('<span>   This content will be added  </span>');


  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this) and [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Code:

```
$(this).closest('.wrapper').append('<span> This content will be added </span>');
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aGC5s/10/

Answer (score 1):

Here my solution :

```
$(".wrapper").on("click", ".button", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(event.delegateTarget).append('<span>   This content will be added  </span>');
});
```

Prefer to delegate event on your wrapper node, especially you want to edit it !

Also keep in mind to call off to free memory.

## UPDATE

By using bind `$(this)` refers to the delegated node (thanks to [Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338292/jack)). This solution is better because there is no need to search in the DOM.

```
$(".wrapper").bind("click", ".button", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).append('<span>   This content will be added  </span>');
});
```

Comment: `$(this)` should be the same as `event.delegateTarget`.

Comment: `$(this)` is `event.currentTarget` when using `.on()` (http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-handler) ! But using bind is better because in that case, `$(this)` is the delegated node.

Comment: Doh, never mind; `event.delegateTarget` points to `.wrapper` of course, which is correct :) +1

Comment: Thanks! Your first comment was right about assuming the direct parent `.wrapper` wasn't a good idea. But I think looking backwards is not so good too.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this)` and `.parent()` See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aGC5s/8/)

Comment: This assumes `.wrapper` is always the parent, but the selector allows non-immediate descendant elements that match `.button`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```
$(this).closest('div.wrapper').append('<span>This content will be added</span>');
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/aGC5s/11/)

Or, maybe this one

```
$(this).parent().append('<span>This content will be added</span>');
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/aGC5s/13/)