# bounce effect not working

Tags: jquery, bounce

I want to make some list items bounce on hover, but can't seem to figure out why it's not working.  This is the link to the coding on jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/wrdweaver6/amhJK/

Here is the code that I am using in my html head:

```
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#nav > li').hover(function() {
              $(this).effect('bounce',{times: 2},'slow');
           });
       });
     </script>   
</head>
```

Here is the body:

```
 <body>

  <div id="nav">

    <ul>
        <li>Word Lists</li>
        <li>Games</li>
        <li>Stories</li>
        <li>Parents</li>
        <li>Email</li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following Js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/arunberti/Dy6h7/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('li a').hover(function() { 
     $(this).parent().effect("bounce", { times:3 }, 'normal');
   }, function () {
     $(this).parent().effect("bounce", { times:3 }, 'normal');
   });
});
```

Also check the following image that you didint add Jquery UI

[image]

Comment: How do I go about adding the Jquery UI into my fiddle and correctly into the html head?  I'm sorry.  I am a beginner, and just started playing around with coding, so I apologize if I sound like a complete idiot at this point.

Comment: @Johnツ This was exactly what I was looking for.  One more question though, if I run the code the way it is, won't I receive a validation error if I try to run it through W3c's html validation service since normally, the <a> tags are on the outside of the <li> tags and not the other way around like in your example?

Comment: Okay.  Nevermind.  I was referring to the answer above yours.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @bliakong lee were you able to resolve the issue?if this helped dont forgot to mark as answer coz some ppl who have answered this post seems to downvote

Comment: @ArunBertil Your jsfiddle was what I wanted, since it did not cause the li elements to stack on top of each other like mine, but I am concerned that the coding will cause an html error when validating since you have your a tags on the inside of your li tags.  I have to run my coding through W3c's html validation service for the class that I am taking.

Answer (score 2):

Two things I noticed:

- One your selector is wrong, it should just be $('#nav li') as li is not a direct child element of the #nav
- Secondly you need to include the jquery UI JS, pretty sure the animations won't work without the JS file.

Comment: I downvoted because the jQuery UI CSS is not needed. Only jQuery UI js is needed in this case.

Comment: Fair enough, I was under the assumption UI was using keyframe CSS animations, but never really looked into it to be honest :) I just always link the CSS

Answer (score 1):

Try out the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav ul>li').click(function(){
        $(this).effect('bounce',{times:3},500);
    });    
})
```

Please find the working demo here: [http://jsfiddle.net/amhJK/9](http://jsfiddle.net/amhJK/9/)/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use `effect()` jQuery UI function.

First of all, the jQuery UI was not imported in your JSFIDDLE.

Import it in your page using the cdn url:

> `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Another problem is that your selector is not correct. `>` is the [**child selector**](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) that *selects all direct child elements specified by "child" of elements specified by "parent".*. So, instead of  `#nav > li` you should use `#nav > ul > li` or `#nav li`, both working.

Another problem is that you use the string `"this"` instead of variable `this` that is **the reference to the DOM element of invocation**. See [**this topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1051782/1420197) for more information.

---

Your script becomes:

```
// on ready callback
$('#nav > ul > li').hover(function(){
    $(this).effect('bounce',{times:3},500);
});
```

[**Updated JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/amhJK/8/)