# how does this line of code works in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I've some second thoughts and I'm a bit confused on this code:
this line of code is the one that I'm wondering about :

```
var items = $("#" + element[0].id + " li");
```

Now my question is: how does this line of code work? so where is the magic here? is it populating the items-array?

**Thanks by the way!**

Is it jquery doing this in one move when we target the **< ul > - element**? (with this code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#slider").mySlider({
                timeOut: 4000,
                captionOpacity: .7            
            });
```

here is some part of the code, the part that I'm wondering about:
let's say u have this html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<script src="js/mySlider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#slider").mySlider({
            timeOut: 4000,
            captionOpacity: .7            
        });
    });
</script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <ul id="slider">
        <li>
            <img src="img/image1.jpg" alt="" />
            <div class="top">
                Some nice text captions..
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="img/image2.jpg" alt="" />
            <div class="bottom">
                Some nice text captions..
            </div>
        </li>

    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

and here the JS:

```
  $.fn.mySlider   = function(vars) {

        var timeOut     = vars.timeOut || 4000;
        var capOpacity  = vars.captionOpacity || .7;
        var element     = this;
        var fxDuration  = timeOut/6;

        var items       = $("#" + element[0].id + " li"); //how do add the < li > items inside this array?
        var captions    = $("#" + element[0].id + " li div");
       // console.log(items);
        items.css('display','none');

        captions.css({
            'opacity': capOpacity,
            'display': 'none'
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the "children" of your LI elements you can use:

```
var items = $("#" + element[0].id + " li").children();
```

jQuery Documentation on [.children(optFilter)](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

With the filter, you can optionally specify that you want only the `DIV`s or `A`s.

e.g.

```
$("#" + element[0].id + " li").children("div");//just the <div>s
$("#" + element[0].id + " li").children("a");//just the <a>s
```

Comment: hit there...Im wondering something else: how jquery populate this array? Does Jquery do it with this line: var items = $("#" + element[0].id + " li")? where is the for-loop or the way jquery works to do this? thanks

Comment: Correct... the line loosely translates to: "set the variable `items` to be equal to a special jQuery set of all `li` elements that are children (of any depth) of the element with the `id` {whateverYouvePassedIn}".

Comment: wow wow so u dont need any for-loop to populate 'var items' uhn? it does it just writing this line of code: var items = $("#" + element[0].id + " li");? and why u write element[0] which is the first item? it should be a variable inside? no?

Comment: Correct... a jQuery selector can return a set of `0`, `1`, or `N` elements that match the selector you provided.  From there you can do whatever you want.  You can "chain" another method e.g. `$("#myId li").hide();` or you can chain the `.each(handler)` method to iterate over the set or you can even extract the actual DOM elements out.

Comment: one more thing: and why do we write a cero inside the brackets  ( $("#" + element[0].id ) and not another nummer? thanks for yr time btw!

Comment: never mind! I think I got the point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this thanks