# How can you refer to an object in jquery that is responsible for triggering the event that calls that function

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
  });
});
```

In the code above I want to call the "button" object and get some attribute values from it inside the function called by clicking the button. How can I do that?

Comment: `this` inside the handler is referring to the element clicked: `alert(this.id);`

Comment: Learn [this](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

Comment: More so `$(this)` than `this` is what they would be looking for.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this on stack overflow is also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try `$(this)`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $(this).val('I WAS CLICKED!');
    $("p").hide();
  });
});
```

hope that helps.

Comment: `that` may not help but `this` might ;-)