# Jquery using calling "this" to call their child element

Tags: jquery

I have this code that came from this link for experiment purposes

[jQuery: What's the difference between '$(this)' and 'this'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this)

```
$("#orderedlist").find("li").each(function(i) {
  $(this).append(" BAM! " + i);
});
```

the code       `$(this).append(" BAM! " + i);`

How do you call the child element of **this**? for example

`$(this + ".className").append(" BAM! " + i);`

Something like that, but it doesn't work.
Any synthax that works for this kind of stuff?

Comment: you can use children() to get all children element of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With method `.find()` you can search inside the object all child levels.
try this;

```
$(this).find(".className").append(" BAM! " + i);
```

If you would like to search only into the first child level you can use `.children()` like this

```
$(this).children(".className").append(" BAM! " + i);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code example. You are iterating through each `<li>` found in `#orderedList` and you are appending the text `BAM! [digit]` so `$(this)` is only referring to the `<li>`

If you did `.append('<span> BAM! ' + i + '</span>')` then you can find the child span like this:

```
var child_text = $(this).append('<span> BAM! ' + i + '</span>').find('span').text();
alert(child_text);
```