# What is the correct way to use "this" in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I want to catch the title attribute of a element from multiple elements having the same class, but different attributes.

This is what I have tried:

**HTML**

```
    <div title="title1" class="pager" onclick="location.href='link.aspx';></div>
    <div title="title2" class="pager" onclick="location.href='link.aspx';></div>
    <div title="title3" class="pager" onclick="location.href='link.aspx';></div>
    <a class="pagerTitle"></a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".pager").bind("mouseover", function() {
        $(".pagerTitle").text(this.attr("title"));
    });
```

But it is not working. What is the correct method to do so?

Comment: You can use like `$(this)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one of two methods:

jQuery:

```
$(this).attr("title")
```

Plain vanilla JavaScript:

```
this.title
```

I'd vote for plain JavaScript so you don't incur the overhead of creating a jQuery object for each tag.

Comment: @Faizan if you believe the problem was solved you should mark this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You used `attr()` method of `jQuery` object, but `this` is not `jQuery` object. Use `$(this)` instead.

Comment: same answer, but thanx

Answer (score 1):

"`$(this)` is one of very popular construct to indicate current element is focus, which can be used inside event and selector functions. This is as equal to JavaScript's `this` construct wrapped by jQuery's function to provide access to jQuery's function."

You should use `$(this)`. Hope it helps!