# unable to remove element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a notifications system. Please refer the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7b3j2/25/).

I tried to close the element using

```
this.remove();
```

It didnt work, no error either.
I also tried:

```
this.parent.remove();
```

This gave an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'remove' of undefined
```

How do I get the close button working properly?

Comment: @gnack Thats not working. It is giving the same behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, `$(this).parent().remove();` (see Arun's answer below)

Comment: Also why was his question voted down?  He asked a perfectly fine question, and explained his problem so well that around 3 people posted an answer almost simultaneously!

Comment: @gnack don't you think that if 3 people can answer it so quickly in under 5 minutes, it might be an "easy to google" kind of question?

Comment: Not if you don't know what you're googling for, he got the syntax correct for removal, he just was performing it on the incorrect object.  You can't google for that without already knowing what you've done wrong - catch 22!

Comment: @RUJordan gnack is right, I didnt knew what to google.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051782/jquery-this-vs-this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` refers to the dom element reference which does not have remove() method, you need the jQuery wrapper for the dom element.

Also you need to remove the parent `div` element

```
    $closeButton.click(function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ufC3p/)